# What's a good algorithm to determine if an input is a perfect square?

Tags: algorithm, math, perfect-square

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

What's a way to see if a number is a [perfect square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number)?

```cs
bool IsPerfectSquare(long input)
{
   // TODO
}
```

I'm using C# but this is language agnostic.

Bonus points for clarity and simplicity (this isn't meant to be code-golf).

---

**Edit:** This got much more complex than I expected! It turns out the problems with double precision manifest themselves a couple ways. First, Math.Sqrt takes a double which can't precisely hold a long (thanks Jon).

Second, a double's precision will lose small values ( .000...00001) when you have a huge, near perfect square. e.g., my implementation failed this test for Math.Pow(10,18)+1 (mine reported true).

Comment: There was a very similar question. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer for an excellent answer.

Comment: To the solution you choose, don't forget to prepend a quick check for negativeness.

Comment: Yes, I had that in there but removed it for brevity. Thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: You could also google for the 'lsqrt' method used for integer square root.

Comment: Michael, Bill the Lizard made a good point that it is just a similar question, not the exact duplicate. I don't think the question needs to be closed. 
Besides the problem of perfect square is much more complex in practical terms than it might seem and the answers here make some great contribution.

Comment: I don't know how fast the method can tell if an integer is a square. This method does not use the square root or Newton's method. It can be found here:   
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226869/how-well-does-this-method-of-checking-if-an-integer-n-is-a-square-perform

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```cs
bool IsPerfectSquare(long input)
{
    long closestRoot = (long) Math.Sqrt(input);
    return input == closestRoot * closestRoot;
}
```

This may get away from *some* of the problems of just checking "is the square root an integer" but possibly not all. You potentially need to get a little bit funkier:

```cs
bool IsPerfectSquare(long input)
{
    double root = Math.Sqrt(input);

    long rootBits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(root);
    long lowerBound = (long) BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(rootBits-1);
    long upperBound = (long) BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(rootBits+1);

    for (long candidate = lowerBound; candidate <= upperBound; candidate++)
    {
         if (candidate * candidate == input)
         {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Icky, and unnecessary for anything other than really large values, but I think it *should* work...

Comment: Looks as if you were faster than me ;-) Oops - your solution is also better, because 'closestRoot' is a far mor accurate name.

Comment: Love the number of upvotes I got *before* correcting it to a more bulletproof solution ;)

Comment: dude, you're jon skeet.

Comment: @Jon:  I'm thinking about rescinding my upvote.  He asked for *clarity* and *simplicity*.  :)

Comment: I assumed accuracy was important. Otherwise I'd have gone for the "guaranteed to be random" kind of response :)

Comment: What's an example input that fails with your first method?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Math.Pow(10,18)+1 will be true with mine...

Comment: You bulletproof solution is not needed. Tested exhaustively and [sort-of proven](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/237865/14435).

Comment: @maaartinus Your comment convinced me to downvote; the second block of code is apparently a bad idea, as it is a complex system that does the same as a much more simple one.

Comment: @Yakk: Whereas I would say that the second piece of code is simpler in terms of being able to understand that it's definitely correct. Put it this way - I find the *code* here much simpler to understand than the *maths* in maaartinus' post on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I dunno.  To be convinced the second one is correct, one must know that both `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` and `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble` cannot throw and is flawless, or that the wrapping code handles any exceptions perfectly.  Understanding the linked proof is *hard* I'll agree; proving every single .net runtime you ever run on doesn't do something stupid is impossible!  ;)  But point taken.

Answer (score 12):

```cs
bool IsPerfectSquare(long input)
{
    long SquareRoot = (long) Math.Sqrt(input);
    return ((SquareRoot * SquareRoot) == input);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Common Lisp, I use the following:

```lisp
(defun perfect-square-p (n)
  (= (expt (isqrt n) 2)
     n))
```

Comment: Heh.  Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/343862/31615, I should add that Common Lisp has a "complete" number stack, so this _just works_ for any non-negative whole number (limited by working memory, of course).

Comment: On SBCL, `square` should be `expt`: `(defun perfect-square-p (n) (= (expt (isqrt n) 2) n))`.

Comment: @BenSima: Actually, since `square` is not defined in the standard, you need to define (or substitute) it in any implementation.  I edit the answer in order not to have such a dependency.