# Shortest way to check perfect Square?

Tags: c#, square-root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good algorithm to determine if an input is a perfect square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343852/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-input-is-a-perfect-square)

I want Shortest and Simplest way to Check a number is perfect square in C#

**Some of Perfect Squares:**

```
1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, ......
```

Comment: @dogbane That question is closed as dup :D

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Probably checking if the square root of the number has any decimal part, or if it is a whole number.

Implementationwise, I would consider something like this:

```
double result = Math.Sqrt(numberToCheck);
bool isSquare = result%1 == 0;
```

`isSquare` should now be `true` for all squares, and `false` for all others.

Comment: +1: I was surprised that the % operator works on doubles

Comment: The above answer is not always correct with large number. Try with this:
    double result = Math.Sqrt ( 3999680306388005621 );
    bool isSquare = result % 1 == 0;
    long x = ( long ) result;
    long y = x * x; // y is not 3999680306388005621

Comment: I'm not sure but that might be when the number starts to lose precision / floating point?

Answer (score 7):

This is a variant on checking if the square root is integral:

```
bool IsPerfectSquare(double input)
{
    var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(input);
    return Math.Abs(Math.Ceiling(sqrt) - Math.Floor(sqrt)) < Double.Epsilon;
}
```

`Math.Ceiling` will round up to the next integer, whereas `Math.Floor` will round down. If they are the same, well, then you have an integer!

This can also be written as a oneliner:

```
if (int(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(n))) == int(Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)))) /* do something */;
```

Comment: `Math.Ceiling()` and `Math.Floor()` return a double value, so you'll run into possible issues here. Instead, do a floating point comparison: `if (Math.Abs(val1 - valu2) < Double.Epsilon) { ... }`

Comment: @michael, thank you, that is a very good point! I have updated my answer to reflect this!

Comment: Any reason to do `< Double.Epsilon` instead of `> 0`?

Answer (score 5):

```
    public bool IsPerferctSquare(uint number)
    {
        return (Math.Sqrt(number) % 1 == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool IsPerfectSquare(int num)
{
   int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(num);
   return (int) Math.Pow(root,2) == num;
}
```