# Number of partition of `n` into sum of three squares (fast algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

A few years ago I found an interesting programming problem:
"To find number of partition of `n` into sum of three squares with `n < 10^9` and 1 second time limit."

Question: Does anyone know how to solve this problem with given constraints?
I think it can be do purely with asymptotic time complexity faster than `O(n)` only? Is there some clever math approach or it is code optimization engineering problem?

I found some info on https://oeis.org/A000164, but there are an `O(n)`-algo in FORMULA section
(because we need to find all divisors of each `n-k^2` number for compute `e(n-k^2)`) and `O(n)`-algo in MAPLE section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First factor the number, `n - z^2`, into primes, decompose the primes into Gaussian conjugates and find different expressions to expand and simplify to get `a + bi`, which can be then raised, `a^2 + b^2`. We can rule out any candidate `n - z^2` that contains a prime of form `4k + 3` with an odd power.

This is based on expressing numbers as Gaussian integer conjugates. `(a + bi)*(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2`. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54839035/2034787

Comment: Are you proposing to factorize each of the 'sqrt(n)' numbers  'n - z^2' ?  But if I factorize sqrt(n) numbers each in average of sqrt(n) operations I will get O(n) time, or not?

Comment: @DmitryPyatin What if we precomputed the relevant primes and only tested each candidate for divisibility by those? On the SO question I referenced, there may be other optimisations to candidate generation.

Comment: @DmitryPyatin the formula in oeis is interesting.

Comment: The problem solved by this way with factorization on only primes 4k+1, 4k+3 less than 'n-z^2' and heuristic primality test for remainder.