# Anybody Knows the Logic To Find Out a Number is Perfect Square or not?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Does Anybody Knows the Logic To Find Out a Number is Perfect Square or not ? (`Other than Newtons Method or Synthetic Division Method`)

```
For Eg:- 4, 16, 36, 64 are Perfect Squares.
```

I will be giving the input as `441`, logic should say whether its a Perfect Square or not.

It was a question asked in Amazon Interview.

I would like to do it with out any built in functions

Comment: [What's a good algorithm to determine if an input is a perfect square?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343852/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-input-is-a-perfect-square)

Comment: If the trick were on the input itself then, Because of 441 has one in the right then no way it could be a Perfect Squares.

Comment: @Jalal: What, like 81 isn't? :-)

Comment: @Jalal - 441 = 21^2. At least check... Besides, take any number that ends with 1, eg, 52941, multiply it by itself, and you get a square that ends with 1.

Comment: @regularfry: @Kobi: I thought that was just for 2 to the power n.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No Math.Sqrt, not even multiplication:

```
    static bool IsSquare(int n)
    {
        int i = 1;
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (n < 0)
                return false;
            if (n == 0)
                return true;
            n -= i;
            i += 2;
        }
    }
```

Note that the squares are the partial sums of the odd integers. `i` takes on the values 1, 3, 5, 7, .... The partial sums 1, 1+3=4, 1+3+5=9, ... are the squares. So after `n -= i` we have subtracted the squares from the original value of `n` and we can compare the result against 0.

Comment: Now try it without addition or multiplication :)

Comment: Have to say, I really like this algorithm.

Comment: Even though from a quick benchmark, it seems that using multiplication is faster.

Comment: Amazing algorithm, hats off dude. i regret why i hate maths :)

Comment: I wish I could offer you bounty of Millions..really appreciated...

Comment: can someone explain how this algorithm is working? What are last two lines doing inside for loop?

Comment: @Flash I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The first question I would ask the interviewer is, "What are the problem constraints?" That is, how big can the input number be?  If it's small enough, then you could just pre-calculate all the perfect sqaures and store them in a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<long, bool> squares = new Dictionary<long, bool>;
for(long i = 1; i*i <= MAX_NUM; ++i) {
    squares[i*i] = true;
}
```

Then, to find out if a number x is a perfect square, you just check squares[x] to see if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this would work.

```
public Boolean IsSquare(double input)
{
    double root, product;
    Boolean isSquare,isGTInput;

    root = 1;
    product = 0;
    isSquare = false;
    isGTInput = false;

    while (!isSquare && !isGTInput)
    {
        product = root * root;
        if (product == input)
            isSquare = true;
        else if (product > input)
            isGTInput = true;

        root += 1;
    }

    return isSquare;

}
```

Comment: will this come under as per i asked

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: As you used `root*root` will this come under as per i asked

Comment: I don't think multiplication would count as a "built in function".  If you can't use multiplication operators, it's probably impossible.