# LINQ flavored IS IN Query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

There are quite a few other questions similiar to this but none of them seem to do what I'm trying to do.  I'd like pass in a list of string and query

```
SELECT ownerid where sysid in ('', '', '') -- i.e. List<string>
```

or like

```
var chiLst = new List<string>();
var parRec = Lnq.attlnks.Where(a => a.sysid IN chiList).Select(a => a.ownerid);
```

I've been playing around with a.sysid.Contains() but haven't been able to get anywhere.

Comment: +1 if you think there should be a first answer to your question by Jon Skeet Badge lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Contains` is the way forward:

```
var chiLst = new List<string>();
var parRec = Lnq.attlnks.Where(a => chiList.Contains(a.sysid))
                        .Select(a => a.ownerid);
```

Although you'd be better off with a `HashSet<string>` instead of a list, in terms of performance, given all the contains checks. (That's assuming there will be quite a few entries... for a small number of values, it won't make much difference either way, and a `List<string>` may even be faster.)

Note that the performance aspect is assuming you're using LINQ to Objects for this - if you're using something like LINQ to SQL, it won't matter as the `Contains` check won't be done in-process anyway.

Comment: For something like Linq to SQL, HashSet won't make any difference, since it just takes all the elements of the list and generates the IN clause.

Comment: @Jon Skeet What is the difference using HashSet<string> Jon ?

Comment: @mellamokb [dude, he's jon skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343852/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-input-is-a-perfect-square#comment178355_343862)

Comment: @Gserg: I know... Cool link btw

Comment: @RobSiklos: True - I was assuming this was being done in-process. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: @GSerg - He works hard to create good answers, though. It's not like he was *born* Jon Sk...oh, nevermind.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: `HashSet<T>` is optimized for efficient containment checks - whereas for `List<T>` it has to check each value in turn.

Comment: @Jon Skeet This does what I need and the HashSet is Faster, win win. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't call `a.sysid.Contains`; the syntax for `IN` (SQL) is the reverse of the syntax for `Contains` (LINQ)

```
var parRec = Lnq.attlnks.Where(a => chiList.Contains(a.sysid))
                        .Select(a => a.ownerid);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `Contains` approach, you could `join`:

```
var parRec = from a in Lnq.attlnks
             join sysid in chiLst
                 on a.sysid equals sysid
             select a.ownerid
```

I'm not sure whether this will do better than `Contains` with a HashSet, but it will at least have similar performance.  It will certainly do better than using `Contains` with a list.

Comment: Assuming LINQ to Objects, it will basically build a `HashSet<string>` within the join implementation. (And it will be faster than a `List<T>` *if the list grows large* - if the list is very short, then a hash-based implementation could be slower, as it needs to generate the hash of the target first. There are all kinds of variables in play, really.)