# Looking for an efficient integer square root algorithm for ARM Thumb2

Tags: embedded, arm, square-root

I am looking for a fast, integer only algorithm to find the square root (integer part thereof) of an unsigned integer.
The code must have excellent performance on ARM Thumb 2 processors. It could be assembly language or C code.

Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 37):

[Integer Square Roots](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programmer-s-toolbox/4219659/Integer-Square-Roots) by Jack W. Crenshaw could be useful as another reference.

The [C Snippets Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20101204075137/http://c.snippets.org/) also has an [integer square root implementation](http://web.archive.org/web/20080303101624/http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=isqrt.c). This one goes beyond just the integer result, and calculates extra fractional (fixed-point) bits of the answer. (Update: unfortunately, the C snippets archive is now defunct. The link points to the web archive of the page.) Here is the code from the C Snippets Archive:

```c
#define BITSPERLONG 32
#define TOP2BITS(x) ((x & (3L << (BITSPERLONG-2))) >> (BITSPERLONG-2))

struct int_sqrt {
    unsigned sqrt, frac;
};

/* usqrt:
    ENTRY x: unsigned long
    EXIT  returns floor(sqrt(x) * pow(2, BITSPERLONG/2))

    Since the square root never uses more than half the bits
    of the input, we use the other half of the bits to contain
    extra bits of precision after the binary point.

    EXAMPLE
        suppose BITSPERLONG = 32
        then    usqrt(144) = 786432 = 12 * 65536
                usqrt(32) = 370727 = 5.66 * 65536

    NOTES
        (1) change BITSPERLONG to BITSPERLONG/2 if you do not want
            the answer scaled.  Indeed, if you want n bits of
            precision after the binary point, use BITSPERLONG/2+n.
            The code assumes that BITSPERLONG is even.
        (2) This is really better off being written in assembly.
            The line marked below is really a "arithmetic shift left"
            on the double-long value with r in the upper half
            and x in the lower half.  This operation is typically
            expressible in only one or two assembly instructions.
        (3) Unrolling this loop is probably not a bad idea.

    ALGORITHM
        The calculations are the base-two analogue of the square
        root algorithm we all learned in grammar school.  Since we're
        in base 2, there is only one nontrivial trial multiplier.

        Notice that absolutely no multiplications or divisions are performed.
        This means it'll be fast on a wide range of processors.
*/

void usqrt(unsigned long x, struct int_sqrt *q)
{
      unsigned long a = 0L;                   /* accumulator      */
      unsigned long r = 0L;                   /* remainder        */
      unsigned long e = 0L;                   /* trial product    */

      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < BITSPERLONG; i++)   /* NOTE 1 */
      {
            r = (r << 2) + TOP2BITS(x); x <<= 2; /* NOTE 2 */
            a <<= 1;
            e = (a << 1) + 1;
            if (r >= e)
            {
                  r -= e;
                  a++;
            }
      }
      memcpy(q, &a, sizeof(long));
}
```

I settled on the following code. It's essentially from the [Wikipedia article on square-root computing methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29). But it has been changed to use `stdint.h` types `uint32_t` etc. Strictly speaking, the return type could be changed to `uint16_t`.

```c
/**
 * \brief    Fast Square root algorithm
 *
 * Fractional parts of the answer are discarded. That is:
 *      - SquareRoot(3) --> 1
 *      - SquareRoot(4) --> 2
 *      - SquareRoot(5) --> 2
 *      - SquareRoot(8) --> 2
 *      - SquareRoot(9) --> 3
 *
 * \param[in] a_nInput - unsigned integer for which to find the square root
 *
 * \return Integer square root of the input value.
 */
uint32_t SquareRoot(uint32_t a_nInput)
{
    uint32_t op  = a_nInput;
    uint32_t res = 0;
    uint32_t one = 1uL << 30; // The second-to-top bit is set: use 1u << 14 for uint16_t type; use 1uL<<30 for uint32_t type


    // "one" starts at the highest power of four <= than the argument.
    while (one > op)
    {
        one >>= 2;
    }

    while (one != 0)
    {
        if (op >= res + one)
        {
            op = op - (res + one);
            res = res +  2 * one;
        }
        res >>= 1;
        one >>= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The nice thing, I discovered, is that a fairly simple modification can return the "rounded" answer. I found this useful in a certain application for greater accuracy. Note that in this case, the return type must be `uint32_t` because the rounded square root of 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 is 2<sup>16</sup>.

```c
/**
 * \brief    Fast Square root algorithm, with rounding
 *
 * This does arithmetic rounding of the result. That is, if the real answer
 * would have a fractional part of 0.5 or greater, the result is rounded up to
 * the next integer.
 *      - SquareRootRounded(2) --> 1
 *      - SquareRootRounded(3) --> 2
 *      - SquareRootRounded(4) --> 2
 *      - SquareRootRounded(6) --> 2
 *      - SquareRootRounded(7) --> 3
 *      - SquareRootRounded(8) --> 3
 *      - SquareRootRounded(9) --> 3
 *
 * \param[in] a_nInput - unsigned integer for which to find the square root
 *
 * \return Integer square root of the input value.
 */
uint32_t SquareRootRounded(uint32_t a_nInput)
{
    uint32_t op  = a_nInput;
    uint32_t res = 0;
    uint32_t one = 1uL << 30; // The second-to-top bit is set: use 1u << 14 for uint16_t type; use 1uL<<30 for uint32_t type


    // "one" starts at the highest power of four <= than the argument.
    while (one > op)
    {
        one >>= 2;
    }

    while (one != 0)
    {
        if (op >= res + one)
        {
            op = op - (res + one);
            res = res +  2 * one;
        }
        res >>= 1;
        one >>= 2;
    }

    /* Do arithmetic rounding to nearest integer */
    if (op > res)
    {
        res++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity I benchmarked a 64-bit conversion of this against the static_casting the C library sqrt function to get an integer result, I found this to be 8.2x slower.  YMMV.  More data at http://onemanmmo.com/?sqrt

Comment: @RobertBasler: It's good that you've measured it. This sort of thing is very hardware-specific; in your case (on a processor with floating-point hardware) it was certainly worth doing a comparison. I expect these integer square-root algorithms would be more useful for embedded systems without floating-point hardware.

Comment: IEEE double-precision floating point can exactly represent integers up to ~53 bits (the size of the mantissa), but beyond that the results are inexact.  One advantage of integer sqrt is that it always gives exact answers.

Comment: For Cortex M3 and brethren, the first loop can be substituted by a leading zero count and mask operation: one >>= clz(op) & ~0x3;  Lops off a good ~30 cycles.

Comment: Avoid UB of shifting in the sign bit with `#define TOP2BITS(x) ((x & (3L << (BITSPERLONG-2))) >> (BITSPERLONG-2))`.  Better as `3L` --> `3UL`.

Answer (score 16):

If exact accuracy isn't required, I have a fast approximation for you, that uses 260 bytes of RAM (you could halve that, but don't).

```c
int ftbl[33]={0,1,1,2,2,4,5,8,11,16,22,32,45,64,90,128,181,256,362,512,724,1024,1448,2048,2896,4096,5792,8192,11585,16384,23170,32768,46340};
int ftbl2[32]={ 32768,33276,33776,34269,34755,35235,35708,36174,36635,37090,37540,37984,38423,38858,39287,39712,40132,40548,40960,41367,41771,42170,42566,42959,43347,43733,44115,44493,44869,45241,45611,45977};

int fisqrt(int val)
{
    int cnt=0;
    int t=val;
    while (t) {cnt++;t>>=1;}
    if (6>=cnt)    t=(val<<(6-cnt));
    else           t=(val>>(cnt-6));

    return (ftbl[cnt]*ftbl2[t&31])>>15;
}
```

Here's the code to generate the tables:

```c
ftbl[0]=0;
for (int i=0;i<32;i++) ftbl[i+1]=sqrt(pow(2.0,i));
printf("int ftbl[33]={0");
for (int i=0;i<32;i++) printf(",%d",ftbl[i+1]);
printf("};\n");

for (int i=0;i<32;i++) ftbl2[i]=sqrt(1.0+i/32.0)*32768;
printf("int ftbl2[32]={");
for (int i=0;i<32;i++) printf("%c%d",(i)?',':' ',ftbl2[i]);
printf("};\n");
```

Over the range 1 → 2<sup>20</sup>, the maximum error is 11, and over the range 1 → 2<sup>30</sup>, it's about 256. You could use larger tables and minimise this. It's worth mentioning that the error will always be negative - i.e. when it's wrong, the value will be LESS than the correct value.

You might do well to follow this with a refining stage.

The idea is simple enough: (ab)<sup>0.5</sup> = a<sup>0.b</sup> × b<sup>0.5</sup>.

So, we take the input X = A×B where A = 2<sup>N</sup> and 1 ≤ B < 2

Then we have a lookup table for sqrt(2<sup>N</sup>), and a lookup table for sqrt(1 ≤ B < 2). We store the lookup table for sqrt(2<sup>N</sup>) as integer, which might be a mistake (testing shows no ill effects), and we store the lookup table for sqrt(1 ≤ B < 2) as 15-bit fixed-point.

We know that 1 ≤ sqrt(2<sup>N</sup>) < 65536, so that's 16-bit, and we know that we can really only multiply 16-bit × 15-bit on an ARM, without fear of reprisal, so that's what we do.

In terms of implementation, the `while(t) {cnt++;t>>=1;}` is effectively a count-leading-bits instruction (CLB), so if your version of the chipset has that, you're winning! Also, the shift instruction would be easy to implement with a bidirectional shifter, if you have one?

There's a Lg[N] algorithm for counting the highest set bit [here.](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

In terms of magic numbers, for changing table sizes, THE magic number for `ftbl2` is 32, though note that *6* (Lg[32]+1) is used for the shifting.

Comment: FWIW, though I don't really recommend this, you can quarter your overall error, with some biasing, viz: int v1=fisqrt(val); v1+=fisqrt(val-v1*v1)/16; 16 is the power of two that works best, over the range 1->2^24.

Answer (score 9):

One common approach is bisection.

```
hi = number
lo = 0
mid = ( hi + lo ) / 2
mid2 = mid*mid
while( lo < hi-1 and mid2 != number ) {
    if( mid2 < number ) {
        lo = mid
    else
        hi = mid
    mid = ( hi + lo ) / 2
    mid2 = mid*mid
```

Something like that should work reasonably well.  It makes log2(number) tests, doing
log2(number) multiplies and divides.  Since the divide is a divide by 2, you can replace it with a `>>`.

The terminating condition may not be spot on, so be sure to test a variety of integers to be sure that the division by 2 doesn't incorrectly oscillate between two even values; they would differ by more than 1.

Comment: `mid*mid` readily overflows the same type as `number`.  Need wider math than `number` here.

Answer (score 9):

I find that most algorithms are based on simple ideas, but are implemented in a way more complicated manner than necessary. I've taken the idea from here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/91040a.pdf (by Ross M. Fosler) and made it into a very short C-function:

```c
uint16_t int_sqrt32(uint32_t x)
{
    uint16_t res= 0;
    uint16_t add= 0x8000;   
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        uint16_t temp=res | add;
        uint32_t g2= (uint32_t)temp * temp;     
        if (x>=g2)
        {
            res=temp;           
        }
        add>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This compiles to 5 cycles/bit on my blackfin. I believe your compiled code will in general be faster if you use for loops instead of while loops, and you get the added benefit of deterministic time (although that to some extent depends on how your compiler optimizes the if statement.)

Comment: Sorry, that should be 5 cycles/bit of the output, which is half as many bits as the input. So 2.5 cycles/bit of the input.

Comment: There's a small bug here. In the expression "temp*temp" you need to cast either of the operands to uint32_t to make sure the multiplication is done in 32-bit arithmetic not 16-bit. The code as-is doesn't work on AVR because of this (but it seems to on platforms where int is 32-bit, due to defaut promotion, but it may still cause integer overflow there).

Comment: Another thing: "uint16_t add= 0x8000;" should be changed to "uint16_t add= UINT16_C(0x8000);".

Comment: I didn't benchmark it, but yields correct results with the suggestions from @AmbrozBizjak, thank you both!

Comment: Well … further optimization: use `do … while(add)` instead of a for loop because the right shift already sets the condition registers, which should save three instructions (two of which are in the loop). In theory. In practice this only works with `clang -Os`, other optimization modes manage to pessimize the code. GCC10 mis-optimizes even worse, I've filed a bug on that.

Answer (score 8):

It's not fast but it's small and simple:

```c
int isqrt(int n)
{
  int b = 0;

  while(n >= 0)
  {
    n = n - b;
    b = b + 1;
    n = n - b;
  }

  return b - 1;
}
```

Comment: Does this use integer overflow?

Answer (score 8):

It depends about the usage of the sqrt function. I often use some approx to make fast versions. For example, when I need to compute the module of vector :

```
Module = SQRT( x^2 + y^2)
```

I use :

```
Module = MAX( x,y) + Min(x,y)/2
```

Which can be coded in 3 or 4 instructions as:

```
If (x > y )
  Module  = x + y >> 1;
Else
   Module  = y + x >> 1;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is the alpha max plus beta min algorithm, using alpha = 1 and beta = 1/2.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_max_plus_beta_min_algorithm

Answer (score 4):

I have settled to something similar to the binary digit-by-digit algorithm described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered the same task on ARM Cortex-M3 (STM32F103CBT6) and after searching the Internet came up with the following solution. It's not the fastest comparing with solutions offered here, but it has good accuracy (maximum error is 1, i.e. LSB on the entire UI32 input range) and relatively good speed (about 1.3M square roots per second on a 72-MHz ARM Cortex-M3 or about 55 cycles per single root including the function call).

```c
// FastIntSqrt is based on Wikipedia article:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots
// Which involves Newton's method which gives the following iterative formula:
//
// X(n+1) = (X(n) + S/X(n))/2
//
// Thanks to ARM CLZ instruction (which counts how many bits in a number are
// zeros starting from the most significant one) we can very successfully
// choose the starting value, so just three iterations are enough to achieve
// maximum possible error of 1. The algorithm uses division, but fortunately
// it is fast enough here, so square root computation takes only about 50-55
// cycles with maximum compiler optimization.
uint32_t FastIntSqrt (uint32_t value)
{
    if (!value)
        return 0;

    uint32_t xn = 1 << ((32 - __CLZ (value))/2);
    xn = (xn + value/xn)/2;
    xn = (xn + value/xn)/2;
    xn = (xn + value/xn)/2;
    return xn;
}
```

I'm using IAR and it produces the following assembler code:

```
        SECTION `.text`:CODE:NOROOT(1)
        THUMB
_Z11FastIntSqrtj:
        MOVS     R1,R0
        BNE.N    ??FastIntSqrt_0
        MOVS     R0,#+0
        BX       LR
??FastIntSqrt_0:
        CLZ      R0,R1
        RSB      R0,R0,#+32
        MOVS     R2,#+1
        LSRS     R0,R0,#+1
        LSL      R0,R2,R0
        UDIV     R3,R1,R0
        ADDS     R0,R3,R0
        LSRS     R0,R0,#+1
        UDIV     R2,R1,R0
        ADDS     R0,R2,R0
        LSRS     R0,R0,#+1
        UDIV     R1,R1,R0
        ADDS     R0,R1,R0
        LSRS     R0,R0,#+1
        BX       LR               ;; return
```

Comment: Nice, on STMG071 with cube ide (gcc) it also takes about 55 instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The most cleverly coded bit-wise integer square root implementations for ARM achieve 3 cycles per result bit, which comes out to a lower bound of 50 cycles for the square root of a 32-bit unsigned integer. An example is shown in Andrew N. Sloss, Dominic Symes, Chris Wright, "ARM System Developer's Guide", Morgan Kaufman 2004.

Since most ARM processors also have very fast integer multipliers, and most even provide a very fast implementation of the wide multiply instruction `UMULL`, an alternative approach that can achieve execution times on the order of 35 to 45 cycles is computation via the reciprocal square root 1/√x using fixed-point computation. For this it is necessary to normalize the input with the help of a count-leading-zeros instruction, which on most ARM processors is available as an instruction `CLZ`.

The computation starts with an initial low-accuracy reciprocal square root approximation from a lookup table indexed by some most significant bit of the normalized argument. The Newton-Raphson iteration to refine the reciprocal square root `r` of a number `a` with quadratic convergence is r<sub>n+1</sub> = r<sub>n</sub> + r<sub>n</sub>* (1 - a * r<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>) / 2. This can be re-arranged into algebraically equivalent forms as is convenient. In the exemplary C99 code below, an 8-bit approximation r<sub>0</sub> is read from a 96-entry lookup table. This approximation is accurate to about 7 bits. The first Newton-Raphson iteration computes r<sub>1</sub> = (3 * r<sub>0</sub> - a * r<sub>0</sub><sup>3</sup>) / 2 to potentially take advantage of small operand multiplication instructions. The second Newton-Raphson iteration computes r<sub>2</sub> = (r<sub>1</sub> * (3 - r<sub>1</sub> * (r<sub>1</sub> * a))) / 2.

The normalized square root is then computed by a back multiplication s<sub>2</sub> = a * r<sub>2</sub> and the final approximation is achieved by denormalizing based on the count of leading zeros of the original argument `a`. It is important that the desired result ⌊√a⌋ is approximated with underestimation. This simplifies the checking whether the desired result has been achieved by guaranteeing that the remainder ⌊√a⌋ - s<sub>2</sub> * s<sub>2</sub> is positive. If the final approximation is found to be too small, the result is increased by one. Correct operation of this algorithm can easily be demonstrated by exhaustive test of all possible 2<sup>32</sup> inputs against a "golden" reference, which takes only a few minutes.

One can speed up this implementation at the expense of additional storage for the lookup table, by pre-computing 3 * r<sub>0</sub> and r<sub>0</sub><sup>3</sup> to simplify the first Newton-Raphson iteration. The former requires 10 bit of storage and the latter 24 bits. In order to combine each pair into a 32-bit data item, the cube is *rounded* to 22 bits, which introduces negligible error into the computation. This results in a lookup table of 96 * 4 = 384 bytes.

An alternative approach uses the observation that all starting approximations have the same most significant bit set, which therefore can be assumed implicitly and does not have to be stored. This allows to squeeze a 9-bit approximation r<sub>0</sub> into an 8-bit data item, with the leading bit restored after table lookup. With a lookup table of 384 entries, all underestimates, one can achieve an accuracy of about 7.5 bits. Combining the back multiply with the Newton-Raphson iteration for the reciprocal square root, one computes s<sub>0</sub> = a * r<sub>0</sub>, s<sub>1</sub> = s<sub>0</sub> + r<sub>0</sub> * (a - s<sub>0</sub> * s<sub>0</sub>) / 2. Because the accuracy of the starting approximation is not high enough for a very accurate final square root approximation, it can be off by up to three, and an appropriate adjustment must be made based on the magnitude of the remainder floor (sqrt (a)) - s<sub>1</sub> * s<sub>1</sub>.

One advantage of the alternative approach is that is halves the number of multiplies required, and in particular requires only a single wide multiplication `UMULL`. Especially processors where wide multiplies are fairly slow, this is an alternative worth trying.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)
#include <intrin.h>
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)

#define CLZ_BUILTIN (1)      // use compiler's built-in count-leading-zeros
#define CLZ_FPU     (2)      // emulate count-leading-zeros via FPU
#define CLZ_CPU     (3)      // emulate count-leading-zeros via CPU

#define ALT_IMPL    (0)      // alternative implementation with fewer multiplies
#define LARGE_TABLE (0)      // ALT_IMPL=0: incorporate 1st NR-iter into table
#define CLZ_IMPL    (CLZ_CPU)// choose count-leading-zeros implementation
#define GEN_TAB     (0)      // generate tables

uint32_t umul32_hi (uint32_t a, uint32_t b);
uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a);
int clz32 (uint32_t a);

#if ALT_IMPL
uint8_t rsqrt_tab [384] = 
{
    0xfe, 0xfc, 0xfa, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0xf4, 0xf2, 0xf0, 0xee, 0xed, 0xeb, 0xe9,
    0xe7, 0xe6, 0xe4, 0xe2, 0xe1, 0xdf, 0xdd, 0xdc, 0xda, 0xd8, 0xd7, 0xd5,
    0xd4, 0xd2, 0xd1, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xcc, 0xcb, 0xc9, 0xc8, 0xc7, 0xc5, 0xc4,
    0xc2, 0xc1, 0xc0, 0xbe, 0xbd, 0xbc, 0xba, 0xb9, 0xb8, 0xb7, 0xb5, 0xb4,
    0xb3, 0xb2, 0xb0, 0xaf, 0xae, 0xad, 0xac, 0xab, 0xa9, 0xa8, 0xa7, 0xa6,
    0xa5, 0xa4, 0xa3, 0xa2, 0xa0, 0x9f, 0x9e, 0x9d, 0x9c, 0x9b, 0x9a, 0x99,
    0x98, 0x97, 0x96, 0x95, 0x94, 0x93, 0x92, 0x91, 0x90, 0x8f, 0x8e, 0x8d,
    0x8c, 0x8b, 0x8b, 0x8a, 0x89, 0x88, 0x87, 0x86, 0x85, 0x84, 0x83, 0x83,
    0x82, 0x81, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x7e, 0x7d, 0x7d, 0x7c, 0x7b, 0x7a, 0x79, 0x79,
    0x78, 0x77, 0x76, 0x75, 0x75, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72, 0x72, 0x71, 0x70, 0x6f,
    0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6b, 0x6a, 0x6a, 0x69, 0x68, 0x67, 0x67,
    0x66, 0x65, 0x65, 0x64, 0x63, 0x63, 0x62, 0x61, 0x61, 0x60, 0x5f, 0x5f,
    0x5e, 0x5d, 0x5d, 0x5c, 0x5c, 0x5b, 0x5a, 0x5a, 0x59, 0x58, 0x58, 0x57,
    0x57, 0x56, 0x55, 0x55, 0x54, 0x54, 0x53, 0x52, 0x52, 0x51, 0x51, 0x50,
    0x50, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x4d, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x4b, 0x4b, 0x4a, 0x4a,
    0x49, 0x48, 0x48, 0x47, 0x47, 0x46, 0x46, 0x45, 0x45, 0x44, 0x44, 0x43,
    0x43, 0x42, 0x42, 0x41, 0x41, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3f, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0x3e, 0x3d,
    0x3d, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x3b, 0x3b, 0x3a, 0x3a, 0x39, 0x39, 0x38, 0x38,
    0x37, 0x37, 0x36, 0x36, 0x36, 0x35, 0x35, 0x34, 0x34, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33,
    0x32, 0x32, 0x31, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x2e, 0x2e, 0x2d,
    0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2c, 0x2c, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x2a, 0x2a, 0x29, 0x29, 0x29,
    0x28, 0x28, 0x27, 0x27, 0x27, 0x26, 0x26, 0x26, 0x25, 0x25, 0x24, 0x24,
    0x24, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x22, 0x22, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
    0x1f, 0x1f, 0x1f, 0x1e, 0x1e, 0x1e, 0x1d, 0x1d, 0x1d, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x1c,
    0x1b, 0x1b, 0x1a, 0x1a, 0x1a, 0x19, 0x19, 0x19, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x17,
    0x17, 0x17, 0x17, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x15, 0x15, 0x15, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14,
    0x13, 0x13, 0x13, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x10, 0x10,
    0x10, 0x0f, 0x0f, 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0e, 0x0e, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0d, 0x0d, 0x0c,
    0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x09,
    0x09, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06,
    0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
    0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

/* compute floor (sqrt (a)) */
uint32_t my_isqrt32 (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t b, r, s, scal, rem;

    if (a == 0) return a;
    /* Normalize argument */
    scal = clz32 (a) & ~1;
    b = a << scal;
    /* Compute initial approximation to 1/sqrt(a) */
    r = rsqrt_tab [(b >> 23) - 128] | 0x100;
    /* Compute initial approximation to sqrt(a) */
    s = umul32_hi (b, r << 8); 
    /* Refine sqrt approximation */
    b = b - s * s;
    s = s + ((r * (b >> 2)) >> 23);
    /* Denormalize result*/
    s = s >> (scal >> 1);
    /* Ensure we got the floor correct */
    rem = a - s * s;
    if      (rem < (2 * s + 1)) s = s + 0;
    else if (rem < (4 * s + 4)) s = s + 1;
    else if (rem < (6 * s + 9)) s = s + 2;
    else                        s = s + 3;
    return s;
}

#else // ALT_IMPL

#if LARGE_TABLE
uint32_t rsqrt_tab [96] = 
{
    0xfa0bfafa, 0xee6b2aee, 0xe5f02ae5, 0xdaf26ed9, 0xd2f002d0, 0xc890c2c4,
    0xc1037abb, 0xb9a75ab2, 0xb4da42ac, 0xadcea2a3, 0xa6f27a9a, 0xa279c294,
    0x9beb4a8b, 0x97a5ca85, 0x9163427c, 0x8d4fca76, 0x89500270, 0x8563ba6a,
    0x818ac264, 0x7dc4ea5e, 0x7a120258, 0x7671da52, 0x72e4424c, 0x6f690a46,
    0x6db24243, 0x6a52423d, 0x67042637, 0x6563c234, 0x62302a2e, 0x609cea2b,
    0x5d836a25, 0x5bfd1a22, 0x58fd421c, 0x5783ae19, 0x560e4a16, 0x53300210,
    0x51c7120d, 0x50623a0a, 0x4da4c204, 0x4c4c1601, 0x4af769fe, 0x49a6b9fb,
    0x485a01f8, 0x471139f5, 0x45cc59f2, 0x448b5def, 0x4214fde9, 0x40df89e6,
    0x3fade1e3, 0x3e8001e0, 0x3d55e1dd, 0x3c2f79da, 0x3c2f79da, 0x3b0cc5d7,
    0x39edc1d4, 0x38d265d1, 0x37baa9ce, 0x36a689cb, 0x359601c8, 0x348909c5,
    0x348909c5, 0x337f99c2, 0x3279adbf, 0x317741bc, 0x30784db9, 0x30784db9,
    0x2f7cc9b6, 0x2e84b1b3, 0x2d9001b0, 0x2d9001b0, 0x2c9eb1ad, 0x2bb0b9aa,
    0x2bb0b9aa, 0x2ac615a7, 0x29dec1a4, 0x29dec1a4, 0x28fab5a1, 0x2819e99e,
    0x2819e99e, 0x273c599b, 0x273c599b, 0x26620198, 0x258ad995, 0x258ad995,
    0x24b6d992, 0x24b6d992, 0x23e5fd8f, 0x2318418c, 0x2318418c, 0x224d9d89,
    0x224d9d89, 0x21860986, 0x21860986, 0x20c18183, 0x20c18183, 0x20000180,
};
#else // LARGE_TABLE
uint8_t rsqrt_tab [96] = 
{
    0xfe, 0xfa, 0xf7, 0xf3, 0xf0, 0xec, 0xe9, 0xe6, 0xe4, 0xe1, 0xde, 0xdc,
    0xd9, 0xd7, 0xd4, 0xd2, 0xd0, 0xce, 0xcc, 0xca, 0xc8, 0xc6, 0xc4, 0xc2,
    0xc1, 0xbf, 0xbd, 0xbc, 0xba, 0xb9, 0xb7, 0xb6, 0xb4, 0xb3, 0xb2, 0xb0,
    0xaf, 0xae, 0xac, 0xab, 0xaa, 0xa9, 0xa8, 0xa7, 0xa6, 0xa5, 0xa3, 0xa2,
    0xa1, 0xa0, 0x9f, 0x9e, 0x9e, 0x9d, 0x9c, 0x9b, 0x9a, 0x99, 0x98, 0x97,
    0x97, 0x96, 0x95, 0x94, 0x93, 0x93, 0x92, 0x91, 0x90, 0x90, 0x8f, 0x8e,
    0x8e, 0x8d, 0x8c, 0x8c, 0x8b, 0x8a, 0x8a, 0x89, 0x89, 0x88, 0x87, 0x87,
    0x86, 0x86, 0x85, 0x84, 0x84, 0x83, 0x83, 0x82, 0x82, 0x81, 0x81, 0x80,
};
#endif //LARGE_TABLE 

/* compute floor (sqrt (a)) */
uint32_t my_isqrt32 (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t b, r, s, t, scal, rem;

    if (a == 0) return a;
    /* Normalize argument */
    scal = clz32 (a) & ~1;
    b = a << scal;
    /* Initial approximation to 1/sqrt(a)*/
    t = rsqrt_tab [(b >> 25) - 32];
    /* First NR iteration */
#if LARGE_TABLE
    r = (t << 22) - umul32_hi (b, t);
#else // LARGE_TABLE
    r = ((3 * t) << 22) - umul32_hi (b, (t * t * t) << 8);
#endif // LARGE_TABLE
    /* Second NR iteration */
    s = umul32_hi (r, b);
    s = 0x30000000 - umul32_hi (r, s);
    r = umul32_hi (r, s);
    /* Compute sqrt(a) = a * 1/sqrt(a). Adjust to ensure it's an underestimate*/
    r = umul32_hi (r, b) - 1;
    /* Denormalize result */
    r = r >> ((scal >> 1) + 11);
    /* Make sure we got the floor correct */
    rem = a - r * r;
    if (rem >= (2 * r + 1)) r++;
    return r;
}
#endif // ALT_IMPL

uint32_t umul32_hi (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)a * b) >> 32);
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

int clz32 (uint32_t a)
{
#if (CLZ_IMPL == CLZ_FPU)
    // Henry S. Warren, Jr, " Hacker's Delight 2nd ed", p. 105
    int n = 158 - (float_as_uint32 ((float)(int32_t)(a & ~(a >> 1))+.5f) >> 23);
    return (n < 0) ? 0 : n;
#elif (CLZ_IMPL == CLZ_CPU)
    static const uint8_t clz_tab[32] = {
        31, 22, 30, 21, 18, 10, 29,  2, 20, 17, 15, 13, 9,  6, 28, 1,
        23, 19, 11,  3, 16, 14,  7, 24, 12,  4,  8, 25, 5, 26, 27, 0
    };
    a |= a >> 16;
    a |= a >> 8;
    a |= a >> 4;
    a |= a >> 2;
    a |= a >> 1;
    return clz_tab [0x07c4acddu * a >> 27] + (!a);
#else // CLZ_IMPL == CLZ_BUILTIN
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)
    return __lzcnt (a);
#else // defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)
    return __builtin_clz (a);
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)
#endif // CLZ_IMPL
}

/* Henry S. Warren, Jr.,  "Hacker's Delight, 2nd e.d", p. 286 */
uint32_t ref_isqrt32 (uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t m, y, b;
    m = 0x40000000U;
    y = 0U;
    while (m != 0) {
        b = y | m;
        y = y >> 1;
        if (x >= b) {
            x = x - b;
            y = y | m;
        }
        m = m >> 2;
    }
    return y;
}

#if defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <windows.h>
double second (void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    static double oofreq;
    static int checkedForHighResTimer;
    static BOOL hasHighResTimer;

    if (!checkedForHighResTimer) {
        hasHighResTimer = QueryPerformanceFrequency (&t);
        oofreq = 1.0 / (double)t.QuadPart;
        checkedForHighResTimer = 1;
    }
    if (hasHighResTimer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter (&t);
        return (double)t.QuadPart * oofreq;
    } else {
        return (double)GetTickCount() * 1.0e-3;
    }
}
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
double second (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec + (double)tv.tv_usec * 1.0e-6;
}
#else
#error unsupported platform
#endif

int main (void)
{
#if ALT_IMPL
    printf ("Alternate integer square root implementation\n");
#else // ALT_IMPL
#if LARGE_TABLE
    printf ("Integer square root implementation w/ large table\n");
#else // LARGE_TAB
    printf ("Integer square root implementation w/ small table\n");
#endif
#endif // ALT_IMPL

#if GEN_TAB
    printf ("Generating lookup table ...\n");
#if ALT_IMPL
      for (int i = 0; i < 384; i++) {
        double x = 1.0 + (i + 1) * 1.0 / 128;
        double y = 1.0 / sqrt (x);
        uint8_t val = (uint8_t)((y * 512) - 256);
        rsqrt_tab[i] = val;
        printf ("0x%02x, ", rsqrt_tab[i]);
        if (i % 12 == 11) printf("\n");
    }
#else // ALT_IMPL
    for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++ ) {
        double x1 = 1.0 + i * 1.0 / 32;
        double x2 = 1.0 + (i + 1) * 1.0 / 32;
        double y = (1.0 / sqrt(x1) + 1.0 / sqrt(x2)) * 0.5;
        uint32_t val = (uint32_t)(y * 256 + 0.5);
#if LARGE_TABLE
        uint32_t cube = val * val * val;
        rsqrt_tab[i] = (((cube + 1) / 4) << 10) + (3 * val);
        printf ("0x%08x, ", rsqrt_tab[i]);
        if (i % 6 == 5) printf ("\n");
#else // LARGE_TABLE
        rsqrt_tab[i] = val;
        printf ("0x%02x, ", rsqrt_tab[i]);
        if (i % 12 == 11) printf ("\n");
#endif // LARGE_TABLE
    }
#endif // ALT_IMPL
#endif // GEN_TAB
    printf ("Running exhaustive test ... ");
    uint32_t i = 0;
    do {
        uint32_t ref = ref_isqrt32 (i);
        uint32_t res = my_isqrt32 (i);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error: arg=%08x  res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", i, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i);

    printf ("PASSED\n");
    printf ("Running benchmark ...\n");
    i = 0;
    uint32_t sum[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double start = second();
    do {
        sum [0] += my_isqrt32 (i + 0);
        sum [1] += my_isqrt32 (i + 1);
        sum [2] += my_isqrt32 (i + 2);
        sum [3] += my_isqrt32 (i + 3);
        sum [4] += my_isqrt32 (i + 4);
        sum [5] += my_isqrt32 (i + 5);
        sum [6] += my_isqrt32 (i + 6);
        sum [7] += my_isqrt32 (i + 7);
        i += 8;
    } while (i);
    double stop = second();
    printf ("%08x \relapsed=%.5f sec\n", 
            sum[0]+sum[1]+sum[2]+sum[3]+sum[4]+sum[5]+sum[6]+sum[7],
            stop - start);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @dancxviii For 64-bit, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187171/fast-integer-square-root-approximation/70428846#70428846)

Comment: @dancxviii For the 32-bit version I *estimated* cycles based on the assembly code generated by latest gcc and Clang and published instruction cycle counts (some implementations have fast `UMULL` others don't). I don't have an ARM platform to run on right now. I had a simpler and faster 64-bit version first, but it failed for rare test cases around 2**63.

Comment: @dancxviii If you have a superior solution, I would suggest posting it in the form of an answer. I tried some simple adjustments to my 64-bit implementation to get the performance back I lost by fixing the functional bug, to no avail. The test failures in my original code were caused by missing the round-off boundary by a tiny epsilon amount for a few dozen arguments out of a trillion test cases. Quite maddening, really.

Comment: @dancxviii One can definitely prove such algorithms correct using a rigorous mathematical approach. To my knowledge, exactly that has been done in other contexts. But I do not possess the necessary know-how. I am a software engineer, not a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Java that combines integer log_2 and Newton's method to create a loop free algorithm. As a downside, it needs division. The commented lines are required to upconvert to a 64-bit algorithm.

```java
private static final int debruijn= 0x07C4ACDD;
//private static final long debruijn= ( ~0x0218A392CD3D5DBFL)>>>6;

static
{
  for(int x= 0; x<32; ++x)
  {
    final long v= ~( -2L<<(x));
    DeBruijnArray[(int)((v*debruijn)>>>27)]= x; //>>>58
  }
  for(int x= 0; x<32; ++x)
    SQRT[x]= (int) (Math.sqrt((1L<<DeBruijnArray[x])*Math.sqrt(2)));
}

public static int sqrt(final int num)
{
  int y;
  if(num==0)
    return num;
  {
    int v= num;
    v|= v>>>1; // first round up to one less than a power of 2 
    v|= v>>>2;
    v|= v>>>4;
    v|= v>>>8;
    v|= v>>>16;
    //v|= v>>>32;
    y= SQRT[(v*debruijn)>>>27]; //>>>58
  }
  //y= (y+num/y)>>>1;
  y= (y+num/y)>>>1;
  y= (y+num/y)>>>1;
  y= (y+num/y)>>>1;
  return y*y>num?y-1:y;
}
```

How this works: The first part produces a square root accurate to about three bits. The line `y= (y+num/y)>>1;` doubles the accuracy in bits. The last line eliminates the roof roots that can be generated.

Comment: I tried 3 other implementations on this page, this one is the fastest when I implemented in C#. Dave Gamble's implementation came in second at about 25% slower than this one. I believe most of the loop based one are just slow...

Comment: Yep, this is probably the fastest you can do on a CPU with division but without a FPU or extended bit manipulation instructions. It is worth noting that the 64 bit version of the algorithm may get better precision for large numbers than an IEEE 754 double on some computers.

Comment: I haven't been able to make this work (assuming `SQRT` and `DeBruijnArray` are both `int[32]`, and adding a necessary cast to `int` to make it compile). It seems to write out of bounds during the first initialization loop.

Comment: The code is tested. The question is if I copied it correctly. One of those is an int[64] in the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

**If you need it just for ARM Thumb 2 processors, CMSIS DSP library by ARM is the best shot for you.** It's made by people who designed Thumb 2 processors. Who else can beat it?

Actually you don't even need an algorithm but specialized square root hardware instructions such as [VSQRT](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Bcfgeabh.html). The ARM company maintains math and DSP algorithm implementations highly optimized for Thumb 2 supported processors by trying to use its hardware like VSQRT. You can get the source code:

- [`arm_sqrt_f32()`](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/7690c3c7ece5ee9be665d756dd105384b30edf09/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h#L5940)
- [`arm_sqrt_q15.c` / `arm_sqrt_q31.c`](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/tree/3b2f0d24e6826f73e54fbab076db6836eedb6990/CMSIS/DSP/Source/FastMathFunctions) (q15 and q31 are the fixed-point data types specialized for ARM DSP core, which is often comes with Thum 2 compatible processors.)

Note that ARM also maintains compiled binaries of CMSIS DSP that guarantees the best possible performance for ARM Thumb architecture-specific instructions. So you should consider statically link them when you use the library. [You can get the binaries here.](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/tree/develop/CMSIS/DSP/Lib/GCC)

Comment: Kim, thanks for this answer, it is certainly useful for many. However, I was looking for an integer square root.

Answer (score 0):

This method is similar to long division: you construct a guess for the next digit of the root, do a subtraction, and enter the digit if the difference meets certain criteria. With a the binary version, your only choice for the next digit is 0 or 1, so you always guess 1, do the subtraction, and enter a 1 unless the difference is negative.

http://www.realitypixels.com/turk/opensource/index.html#FractSqrt

Answer (score -1):

I implemented Warren's suggestion and the Newton method in C# for 64-bit integers. Isqrt uses the Newton method, while Isqrt uses Warren's method. Here is the source code:

```cs
using System;

namespace Cluster
{
    public static class IntegerMath
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the integer square root, the largest whole number less than or equal to the true square root of N.
        /// 
        /// This uses the integer version of Newton's method.
        /// </summary>
        public static long Isqrt(this long n)
        {
            if (n < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n", "Square root of negative numbers is not defined.");
            if (n <= 1) return n;

            var xPrev2 = -2L;
            var xPrev1 = -1L;
            var x = 2L;
            // From Wikipedia: if N + 1 is a perfect square, then the algorithm enters a two-value cycle, so we have to compare 
            // to two previous values to test for convergence.
            while (x != xPrev2 && x != xPrev1)
            {
                xPrev2 = xPrev1;
                xPrev1 = x;
                x = (x + n/x)/2;
            }
            // The two values x and xPrev1 will be above and below the true square root. Choose the lower one.
            return x < xPrev1 ? x : xPrev1;
        }

        #region Sqrt using Bit-shifting and magic numbers.

        // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100090/looking-for-an-efficient-integer-square-root-algorithm-for-arm-thumb2
        // Converted to C#.
        private static readonly ulong debruijn= ( ~0x0218A392CD3D5DBFUL)>>6;
        private static readonly ulong[] SQRT = new ulong[64];
        private static readonly int[] DeBruijnArray = new int[64];

        static IntegerMath()
        {
          for(int x= 0; x<64; ++x)
          {
            ulong v= (ulong) ~( -2L<<(x));
            DeBruijnArray[(v*debruijn)>>58]= x;
          }
          for(int x= 0; x<64; ++x)
            SQRT[x]= (ulong) (Math.Sqrt((1L<<DeBruijnArray[x])*Math.Sqrt(2)));
        }

        public static long Isqrt2(this long n)
        {
          ulong num = (ulong) n; 
          ulong y;
          if(num==0)
            return (long)num;
          {
            ulong v= num;
            v|= v>>1; // first round up to one less than a power of 2 
            v|= v>>2;
            v|= v>>4;
            v|= v>>8;
            v|= v>>16;
            v|= v>>32;
            y= SQRT[(v*debruijn)>>58];
          }
          y= (y+num/y)>>1;
          y= (y+num/y)>>1;
          y= (y+num/y)>>1;
          y= (y+num/y)>>1;
          // Make sure that our answer is rounded down, not up.
          return (long) (y*y>num?y-1:y);
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

I used the following to benchmark the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Cluster;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ClusterTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegerMathTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Isqrt_Accuracy()
        {
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 100000L; n++)
            {
                var expectedRoot = (long) Math.Sqrt(n);
                var actualRoot = n.Isqrt();
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedRoot, actualRoot, String.Format("Square root is wrong for N = {0}.", n));
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Isqrt2_Accuracy()
        {
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 100000L; n++)
            {
                var expectedRoot = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);
                var actualRoot = n.Isqrt2();
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedRoot, actualRoot, String.Format("Square root is wrong for N = {0}.", n));
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Isqrt_Speed()
        {
            var integerTimer = new Stopwatch();
            var libraryTimer = new Stopwatch();

            integerTimer.Start();
            var total = 0L;
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 300000L; n++)
            {
                var root = n.Isqrt();
                total += root;
            }
            integerTimer.Stop();

            libraryTimer.Start();
            total = 0L;
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 300000L; n++)
            {
                var root = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);
                total += root;
            }
            libraryTimer.Stop();

            var isqrtMilliseconds = integerTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var libraryMilliseconds = libraryTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var msg = String.Format("Isqrt: {0} ms versus library: {1} ms", isqrtMilliseconds, libraryMilliseconds);
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            Assert.IsTrue(libraryMilliseconds > isqrtMilliseconds, "Isqrt2 should be faster than Math.Sqrt! " + msg);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Isqrt2_Speed()
        {
            var integerTimer = new Stopwatch();
            var libraryTimer = new Stopwatch();

            var warmup = (10L).Isqrt2();

            integerTimer.Start();
            var total = 0L;
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 300000L; n++)
            {
                var root = n.Isqrt2();
                total += root;
            }
            integerTimer.Stop();

            libraryTimer.Start();
            total = 0L;
            for (var n = 0L; n <= 300000L; n++)
            {
                var root = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);
                total += root;
            }
            libraryTimer.Stop();

            var isqrtMilliseconds = integerTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var libraryMilliseconds = libraryTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var msg = String.Format("isqrt2: {0} ms versus library: {1} ms", isqrtMilliseconds, libraryMilliseconds);
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            Assert.IsTrue(libraryMilliseconds > isqrtMilliseconds, "Isqrt2 should be faster than Math.Sqrt! " + msg);
        }

    }
}
```

My results on a Dell Latitude E6540 in Release mode, Visual Studio 2012 were
that the Library call Math.Sqrt is faster.

- 59 ms - Newton (Isqrt)
- 12 ms - Bit shifting (Isqrt2)
- 5 ms - Math.Sqrt

I am not clever with compiler directives, so it may be possible to tune the compiler to get the integer math faster. Clearly, the bit-shifting approach is very close to the library. On a system with no math coprocessor, it would be very fast.

Answer (score -2):

I've designed a 16-bit sqrt for RGB gamma compression. It dispatches into 3 different tables, based on the higher 8 bits. Disadvantages: it uses about a kilobyte for the tables, rounds unpredictable, if exact sqrt is impossible, and, in the worst case, uses single multiplication (but only for a very few input values).

```c
static uint8_t sqrt_50_256[] = {
  114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,
  133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,
  150,151,152,153,154,155,155,156,157,158,159,159,160,161,162,163,163,164,165,
  166,167,167,168,169,170,170,171,172,173,173,174,175,175,176,177,178,178,179,
  180,181,181,182,183,183,184,185,185,186,187,187,188,189,189,190,191,191,192,
  193,193,194,195,195,196,197,197,198,199,199,200,201,201,202,203,203,204,204,
  205,206,206,207,207,208,209,209,210,211,211,212,212,213,214,214,215,215,216,
  217,217,218,218,219,219,220,221,221,222,222,223,223,224,225,225,226,226,227,
  227,228,229,229,230,230,231,231,232,232,233,234,234,235,235,236,236,237,237,
  238,238,239,239,240,241,241,242,242,243,243,244,244,245,245,246,246,247,247,
  248,248,249,249,250,250,251,251,252,252,253,253,254,254,255,255
};

static uint8_t sqrt_0_10[] = {
  1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,
  11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,
  15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,
  18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,
  20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,
  23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,
  25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,
  27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,
  28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,
  30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,
  32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,
  33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,
  35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,
  36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,
  37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,
  39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,
  40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,
  41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,
  42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,
  43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,
  45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,
  46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,
  47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,
  48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,
  49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,
  50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,
  51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,
  52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,53,53
};

static uint8_t sqrt_11_49[] = {
  54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,0,76,77,78,
  0,79,80,81,82,83,0,84,85,86,0,87,88,89,0,90,0,91,92,93,0,94,0,95,96,97,0,98,0,
  99,100,101,0,102,0,103,0,104,105,106,0,107,0,108,0,109,0,110,0,111,112,113
};

uint16_t isqrt16(uint16_t v) {
  uint16_t a, b;
  uint16_t h = v>>8;
  if (h <= 10) return v ? sqrt_0_10[v>>2] : 0;
  if (h >= 50) return sqrt_50_256[h-50];
  h = (h-11)<<1;
  a = sqrt_11_49[h];
  b = sqrt_11_49[h+1];
  if (!a) return b;
  return b*b > v ? a : b;
}
```

I've compared it against the log2 based sqrt, using clang's `__builtin_clz` (which should expand to a single assembly opcode), and the library's `sqrtf`, called using `(int)sqrtf((float)i)`. And got rather strange results:

```
$ gcc -O3 test.c -o test && ./test 
isqrt16: 6.498955
sqrtf: 6.981861
log2_sqrt: 61.755873
```

Clang compiled the call to `sqrtf` to a `sqrtss` instruction, which is nearly as fast as that table `sqrt`. Lesson learned: on x86 the compiler can provide fast enough `sqrt`, which is less than 10% slower than what you yourself can come up with, wasting a lot of time, or can be 10 times faster, if you use some ugly bitwise hacks. And still `sqrtss` is a bit slower than custom function, so if you really need these 5%, you can get them, and ARM for example has no `sqrtss`, so log2_sqrt shouldn't lag that bad.

On x86, where FPU is available, the [old Quake hack](http://h14s.p5r.org/2012/09/0x5f3759df.html?mwh=1) appears to be the fastest way to calculate integer sqrt. It is 2 times faster than this table or the FPU's sqrtss.