# Integer functions of square and square root

Tags: go

Currently, `math.Pow()` and `math.sqrt` take `float64` type arguments.

Do we have equivalent functions that take `int` type arguments?

Comment: You can check here http://golang.org/pkg/math/, they are not provided.

Answer (score 5):

If your return value is a float, you can use Ceil or Floor from the math package and then convert it to an int.

```
n := 5.5
o := math.Floor(n)
p := int(math.Pow(o, 2))

fmt.Println("Float:", n)
fmt.Println("Floor:", o)
fmt.Println("Square:", p)

5.5
5
25
```

Keep in mind that Floor still returns a float64, so you will still want to wrap it in int()

Answer (score 4):

just create a float64 object using the int value. Example if int = 10.

```
var x float64 = 10
var b = math.Pow(2, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are fast approximate algorithms described elsewhere on SO, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100090/looking-for-an-efficient-integer-square-root-algorithm-for-arm-thumb2). If performance is important, porting one of the C algorithms to Go might be worth the effort.

Answer (score -3):

What you can do is type-cast a **float** to your value.

```
int a=10,b=2;
math.Pow(float(a),float(b));
```