# Square root of natural numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
example

root of 1 as 1*sqrt{1}

root of 2 as 1*sqrt{2}

root of 3 as 1*sqrt{3}

root of 9 as 3*sqrt{1}
```

I tried to find a algorithm like below:

```
for(i=sqrt(n);i>=1;i--)
if(n%(i*i)==0) {
    break;
}
cout<<i<<' '<<n/(i*i)<<endl;
```

but it is not good when n is big number

so can you tell me a algorithm for this problem ?
thank you so much!

Comment: Please describe what you want to calculate. This is definitely not the square root.

Comment: no the answers must be nature numbers

Comment: I think what the OP wants to achieve is to extract the greatest perfect square `a*a` from under the root, so that `a` can be moved outside. `sqrt(a*a*b) == a*sqrt(b)`. It's just a simplification of the expression.

Comment: What is that `3*sqrt{1}` notation supposed to mean?  that `sqrt(9) == 3*sqrt(1)`?  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100090/looking-for-an-efficient-integer-square-root-algorithm-for-arm-thumb2 for an O(log n) `isqrt`  (i.e. linear in the number of bits in the binary representation).

Comment: Looking at your example series, it seems that what you want to do is to *find the perfect square factors of `n`*. Perfect square factors can be moved outside of the square root as an integer. If that's the case, then please put that in the question. *square root of natural numbers* means just square root: you can calculate that with `sqrt(n)` and the result itself won't be a natural number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you expecting your code to do? For a given `n` you're finding the largest number `i` whose square divides `n`. If `n` is prime, for instance (say n=5, 17, etc.) this condition can only be satisfied if `i=1`, so you're going to wind up with the result `1` a lot of the time.

Comment: That should have been a comment, it's definitely not an answer.

Comment: @DarkDust I guess we should close as off topic since it's a shopping list question for a square root algo, and edit the irrelevant code out of the question.

Comment: can you show me a new algo which faster than my algo?

Comment: @RoadHuman google it?

Answer (score 1):

The question does not account for perfect/non-perfect squares. Since the square root can be a float/double, an iterative approach is a more precise way to find the root.

This link might help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296102/fastest-square-root-algorithm