# What's the math theory behind Apple's square root of fixed point algorithm

Tags: microcontroller, fixed-point, square-root

I'm working in a project where I need to calculate the square root of a 16-bit number. I'm using a NXP micro-controller that doesn't have support for float point operation. Looking online I found the following approach [Fixed-Point Square Root by Ken Turkowsky from Apple](https://books.google.com/books?id=ekGjBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=apple%20fixed%20point%20square%20root&source=bl&ots=Zng7O8II7N&sig=XGWHjkjrgDa8Zydk0UG-M670loE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH9b7X6ZXXAhWrhlQKHebPDpoQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=apple%20fixed%20point%20square%20root&f=false). I also found the same algorithm with some modifications around the WEB including here: [Looking for an efficient integer square root algorithm for ARM Thumb2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100090/looking-for-an-efficient-integer-square-root-algorithm-for-arm-thumb2)
I'm copying the code here in order to make it available in case of a broken link:

```
    void put_space(unsigned int number)
{
    int i;
    char spaces = 12;
    char buffer[15];
    char number_of_chars = sprintf(buffer,"%u",number);
    for(i=0;i<spaces-number_of_chars;i++)
    {
        printf(" ");    
    }   
}
void print_binary(unsigned int number)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char bit;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        if(i%8 == 0 && i!=0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        bit = (number & (2147483648 >> i)) == (2147483648 >> i);
        printf("%u",bit);
    }
}
void print_number(unsigned int number)
{
    print_binary(number);
    printf(" ");
    printf("(%u)",number);
    put_space(number);
}


typedef signed int TFract; /* 2 integer bits, 30 fractional bits */
    TFract FFracSqrt(TFract x)
    {
        register unsigned int root, remHi, remLo, testDiv, count;
        root = 0; /* Clear root */ printf("root: "); print_number(root);        
        remHi = 0; /* Clear high part of partial remainder */  printf("remHi: "); print_number(remHi);
        remLo = x; /* Get argument into low part of partial remainder */ printf("remLo: "); print_number(remLo);
        count = 30; /* Load loop counter */

        printf("\n\n");
    do 
    {
        remHi = (remHi<<2) | (remLo>>30); printf("remHi: "); print_number(remHi);
        remLo <<= 2; /* get 2 bits of arg */ printf("remLo: "); print_number(remLo);
        root <<= 1; /* Get ready for the next bit in the root */ printf("root: "); print_number(root);
        testDiv = (root << 1) + 1; /* Test radical */ printf("testDiv: "); print_number(testDiv);       
        if (remHi >= testDiv) 
        {
            remHi -= testDiv; printf("remHi: "); print_number(remHi);
            root++; printf("root: "); print_number(root);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while (count-- != 0);

    printf("\n\nResult: %u\n\n",root);  
    return(root);
}
```

I can understand what is going on in the algorithm including the shifts and the OR operation. However, I can't comprehend the mathematics behind this code.
FFracSqrt receives a "x" integer number as parameter and returns floor(sqrt(x)*32768). How does that happen?
Please, help me and other people to understand it because I couldn't find anything about the theory so far.
Sincerely,

I'm adding here the output when input is 2:
Before do-while loop
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 (2)

Into do-while loop
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 (8)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000 (32)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 (128)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 (512)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 (2048)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00100000 00000000 (8192)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 (32768)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 (131072)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 (524288)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 00100000 00000000 00000000 (2097152)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 (8388608)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 (33554432)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (134217728)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (536870912)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
remLo:   10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (2147483648)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 (2)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (1)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 (4)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 (2)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 (5)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000 (16)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 (4)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001 (9)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111 (7)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 (5)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00011100 (28)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010 (10)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010101 (21)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111 (7)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00001011 (11)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00011100 (28)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00010110 (22)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101101 (45)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 01110000 (112)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00101100 (44)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01011001 (89)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010111 (23)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00101101 (45)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 01011100 (92)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 01011010 (90)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110101 (181)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000001 01110000 (368)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 10110100 (180)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000001 01101001 (361)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111 (7)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000000 10110101 (181)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00011100 (28)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000001 01101010 (362)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000010 11010101 (725)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000000 01110000 (112)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000010 11010100 (724)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00000101 10101001 (1449)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000001 11000000 (448)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00000101 10101000 (1448)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00001011 01010001 (2897)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00000111 00000000 (1792)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00001011 01010000 (2896)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00010110 10100001 (5793)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 00011100 00000000 (7168)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00010110 10100000 (5792)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 00101101 01000001 (11585)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 01110000 00000000 (28672)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 00101101 01000000 (11584)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 01011010 10000001 (23169)
If condition TRUE
remHi:   00000000 00000000 00010101 01111111 (5503)
root:    00000000 00000000 00101101 01000001 (11585)

remHi:   00000000 00000000 01010101 11111100 (22012)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 01011010 10000010 (23170)
testDiv: 00000000 00000000 10110101 00000101 (46341)

remHi:   00000000 00000001 01010111 11110000 (88048)
remLo:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (0)
root:    00000000 00000000 10110101 00000100 (46340)
testDiv: 00000000 00000001 01101010 00001001 (92681)

Result:  46340

Comment: did you walk through the math with pencil and paper?

Comment: I did even better. I modified the algorithm to show the numbers in binary. As I said, I know what's going on but I can't understand the mathematics.

Comment: Wikipedia has [a good collection of square root methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). The above looks a lot like binary digit-by-digits approach detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29).

Comment: As pointed out by John McFarlane, this code implements the centuries-old long square root algorithm that used to be taught in schools prior to the advent of handheld calculator. This variant operates in base 2, thus generating one bit of result per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here my attempt with comments

```
TFract FFracSqrt(TFract x)
{
   unsigned root = 0; /* Clear root */

   //remHi & remLo forming a 64bit unsigned integer
   //remHiLo containing the remainder from the radicant not yet transfered into root
   unsigned remHi = 0;
   unsigned remLo = x;

   unsigned bitcount = 30; /* Load loop counter */

   do 
   {
       //shift left the remHiLo package by two bit positions
       remHi = (remHi<<2) | (remLo>>30);
       remLo <<= 2;

       //As we multiplied remHiLo with 4, it is fair to multiply the root with sqrt(4)
       root <<= 1;

       //We just shifted in a zero bit in root. Should it be set?

       //We should check whether (root+1) is too large

       //(root+1) * (root+1)
       //root^2 + 2*root + 1

       //We always deduct root^2 from remHi, so we need to check only the delta
       //between root^2 and (root+1)^2

       unsigned testDiv = (root << 1) + 1;

       if (remHi < testDiv)
       {
          //root+1 would overshoot the radicant, so leave everything as it is
       } 
       else
       {
           root++; //set LSB
           remHi -= testDiv; //update remHi to reflect the new bit in root
       }
    } while (bitcount-- != 0);
    return root;
```