# Finding perfect square

Tags: python

I have this python code:

```
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans < x:
            ans = ans + 1
            if ans*ans != x:
                print x, 'is not a perfect square.'
                return None
            else:
                print x, ' is a perfect square.'
                return ans
    else:
        print x, ' is not a positive number.'
        return None

y = 16      
sqrt(y)
```

the output is:

```
16 is not a perfect square.
```

Whereas this works perfectly:

```
x = 16
ans = 0
if x >= 0:
    while ans*ans < x:
        ans = ans + 1
        #print 'ans =', ans
    if ans*ans != x:
        print x, 'is not a perfect square'  
    else: print ans, 'is a perfect square'
else: print x, 'is not a positive number'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is a related question on finding whether a number is a perfect square: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indent your code correctly to let the `while` statement execute until `ans*ans < x`:

```
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans < x:
            ans = ans + 1

        if ans*ans != x:  # this if statement was nested inside the while
            print x, 'is not a perfect square.'
            return None
        else:
            print x, ' is a perfect square.'
            return ans
    else:
        print x, ' is not a positive number.'
        return None

y = 16          
print sqrt(y)
```

Try it out [here](http://codepad.org/dnxYtH5t).

Comment: Aah! I was going crazy over this, indentation while really helps in reading the code can be really difficult to debug! :)

Comment: Give me Python's indentation rules any day over the possibility my indentation may not match my braces in C et al. It's a lot easier if you make sure your editor is configured for spaces only.

Answer (score 10):

Just thought I'd contribute a simpler solution:

```
def is_square(n):
    return sqrt(n).is_integer()
```

**This is valid for `n < 2**52 + 2**27 = 4503599761588224`.**

Examples:

```
>>> is_square(4)
True
>>> is_square(123)
False
>>> is_square(123123123432**2)
True
```

Comment: While a good answer for *small* values, this has precision problems. `is_square(123456789123456789**7-1)` gives `True`. There's no particularly easy solution, though. [I don't think `123123123432156156165**7` is square anyway.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+123456789123456789**7+square).

Comment: and 123123123432**7 is not a perfect square:
its sqrt lies between 654920651322780642131484946101910838253 and 654920651322780642131484946101910838254

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop only executes once. No matter which branch the `if` statement inside it takes, the whole function will return immediately.

Comment: Strange! The same code works outside the function, why is that?

Comment: Because the loop outside the function is not being exited prematurely with a return.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I modified it, tried it out, and it works. You just need this piece of code

As soon as ans = 4, ans * ans is no longer smaller than x. Try while ans*ans <= x:  instead of just <

```
def sqrt(x):
ans = 0
if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans <= x:                     
                if ans*ans == x:
                            print x, ' is a perfect square.'
                            return ans
        else:
            ans = ans + 1
```

Comment: You can't return in your loop in the case where ans*ans is not x.
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans <= x:
                ans = ans + 1
                if ans*ans == x:
                        print x, ' is a perfect square.'
                        return ans
    else:
        print x, ' is not a positive number.'
        return None
 print x, 'is not a perfect square.'
    return None
 
y = 16          
sqrt(y)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so it displays the value of `ans` as well as `x`, so you can tell how many times the loop is executed.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but I could recognise the same problem as Greg Hewgill.

Answer (score 0):

If your code sample is actually correctly indentet the first round of the while will return on it's first round - always. So any positive value of x>1 will fullfil the ans*ans=1*1=1!=x, giving "x is not a perfect square".

You basically needs to get your indentation right - like you do in your other example. Again - if your code sample here actually is correctly indented. Try this:

```
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans < x:
            ans = ans + 1

        if ans*ans != x:
            print x, 'is not a perfect square.'
            return None
        else:
            print x, ' is a perfect square.'
            return ans
    else:
        print x, ' is not a positive number.'
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPerfectSquare(number):
    return len(str(math.sqrt(number)).split('.')[1]) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably short.

```
 def issquare():
      return (m**.5 - int(m**.5)==0)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to determine whether a number is a perfect square, I would think it would be simpler (and perhaps more efficient) to use math builtins, e.g.:

```
def is_perfect_square(n):
  if not ( ( isinstance(n, int) or isinstance(n, long) ) and ( n >= 0 ) ):
    return False 
  else:
    return math.sqrt(n) == math.trunc(math.sqrt(n))
```

Comment: This returns True for `(2**64) - 1` -- you're losing precision

Comment: Not relevant criticism, despite being true. This isnt a pure math page, this is a programming site. You cannot even store irrational numbers in computers. Precision is never infinite; thats the point of computers and anyone whose done any programming knows this ahead of time. Dont see a reason for criticizing. Numbers that large wont be tested except by mathematicians who probably have better notions and wont be on this site.