# Is there any method (not modulo) to grab the remainder of number?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a ruby kata to return an array of perfect squares given an array. A perfect square such as 4 will yield 2.0. A number that isn't perfect will be a decimal like 2.343 etc. I want to make it work so that, if the tenths place is anything other than zero, it will drop the number. Any thoughts?

I would use modulo, but I don't think there's a use for what I'm trying to do. I was wondering if there was a method other than modulo that could grab the remainder of a number for comparison. I saw the ruby docs for `zero?`, `divmod`, and a few others, but they don't do exactly what I need.

Here is my code:

```
def get_squares(array)
  array.to_a.drop_while do |number|
    Math.sqrt(number) #== drop if remainder is something other than .0
  end
end

get_squares((1..16))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if the tenths place is anything other than zero, it will drop the number"? Do you mean that, if the square root of `num` is something like `3.382247284074723...`, then keep `num`, but if it is something like `3.382247284374923...` then it is supposed to be removed from the array?

Comment: Hey @sawa. I got the answer already but what I was trying to communicate was that if the number was for example 2.0 keep it, but if it was 3.2456 from an imperfect square then it needed to be dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
class Float
  def is_int?
    self.to_i == self
  end
end

def get_squares(array)
  array.select { |number| Math.sqrt(number).is_int? }
end
```

Comment: [IEEE 745](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) => `Math.sqrt(1234567890**2 - 1).is_int? == true`. Instead ot this he/she should use pure integer solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435/how-could-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square.

Comment: I agree that he shouldn't calculate square roots for every number, however this is not what he asked for.