# Python: Brown numbers and overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that calculates Brown numbers, or numbers that can be expressed as `n!+1 = m^2` where m is an integer, and running this through creates too big of a number.

Any idea how to fix this? (There is also an abacist style method but it takes exponentially longer)

```
n = 40320
f = 9
while True:
    x = (n+1)**(.5)
    if isinstance( x, int ):
        break
    else:
        n = n*f
        f = f+1
print(f)
print(n)
print(input(" "))
```

*n is 8!

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you never calculate `n!`. `n` and `f` always increase

Comment: 8!  = 40320, and a factorial is just 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 so doing 9*8! = 9!

Comment: Right... And you are going to hit an overflow error eventually at some point, regardless of any provided "fix". So what is the issue?

Comment: I need either some way to circumvent the problem as to continue through a large amount of numbers so I can do these calculations
Also I'm trying to figure out why it starts with the overflow error

Comment: [Only three such numbers are known](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Brown+numbers). And 9 is much higher than *any* of those values... Python (and most programming languages) are limited by hard integer & floating point size limits of your computer.

Comment: The highest one is 7(7!+1= 71^2) , and the program begins at 8!, 40320. I assume by that means that it's a computer hard limit then.

Comment: Yeah, your code crashes from an overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never end because `x` will never be of type `int`:

```
>>> 4**0.5
2.0
>>> isinstance(4**0.5, int)
False
>>> isinstance(4**0.5, float)
True
```

May I suggest this alternative:

```
x = (n+1)**(.5)
x = int(round(x))
if x ** 2 == n + 1:
    break
```

This should also handle floating point accuracy issues.

EDIT: the above was a simple method for small numbers. To check if a large number is a perfect square there are other methods such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489519/2482744

Comment: This still ends with a "OverflowError: int too large to convert to float" error

Comment: @Z.B where is this happening? I don't see where I'm converting to a float.

Comment: line 4, in what x equals

Comment: while `isinstance(4**0.5, int) == False`, `(4**0.5).is_integer() == True`.

Comment: @Z.B updated my answer, basically just pointing to a better answer.