# for loop colon invalid syntax + print invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this code.

```
Number=int(input("Enter:  ")
for x in Number:
    if Number is x*x:
        print("It's a perfect square!")
    else:
        print("It's not a perfect square")
```

I got an invalid syntax error on the colons and the print when I run the code.Can somebody tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html) because you are making mistakes in several fundamental areas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: In order to check whether number is a perfect square, you may check: [How could I check if a number is a perfect square?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435/how-could-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First reason for your error is "Close brace missing in First Line.".
even if you correct this, there is a logical error in your code.

Comment: Your post boils down to "there is a typo" (which is best solved in a comment, as such questions are not on-topic for this site), with a note that this answer is missing other useful information. This isn't useful.