# Testing if some value is not produced by an iterator

Tags: python, iterator, sequence, fibonacci, iterable

I would like to test whether a certain value belongs to a sequence of numbers, which is produced using an iterator. Of course when the value **does** belong to the sequence, one can stop as soon as the value is met. But when it **does not**, I guess that's when problems show up.

However one can use additional information (e.g., the sequence is increasing).

Consider the Fibonacci example:

```
class FibonacciIterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem = [0, 1]
    def __next__(self):
        curr = self.mem[0]
        new = self.mem[0]+self.mem[1]
        self.mem[0] = self.mem[1]
        self.mem[1] = new
        return curr

class Fibonacci(object):
    def __iter__(self):
       return FibonacciIterator()
```

If one tests whether `8` belongs to the sequence then everything is fine:

```
>>> fib = Fibonacci()
>>> 8 in fib
True
```

If, however, one tests `10` (which doesn't belong to the sequence) then

```
>>> 10 in fib
...
```

never terminates. But one could easily determine that `10` is not in the sequence by observing that after `8` comes `13`, and since the sequence is increasing then necessarily `not 10 in fib`.

Is there a nice way in Python to implement such behavior of `in`, so that `10 in fib` terminates?

Comment: You can provide a definition of `__contains__` that knows that the sequence is monotonically increasing. However, for a generator, `__contains__` would *consume* the sequence, so it may not be particularly useful.

Comment: seems like a problem where you are not testing weather the number has exceeded the input

Comment: @chepner that's indeed the way: the fact that the iterator gets consumed is not a big deal in my example above, since I would define `__contains__` in the `Fibonacci` class (the "iterable") to produce a new `FibonacciIterator` (the "iterator") every time `in` is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial solution would be to implement a [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method that just iterates over a copy of the iterator:

```
class FibonacciIterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem = [0, 1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __contains__(self, value):
        testit = FibonacciIterator()
        testit.mem = list(self.mem)  # copy
        for item in testit:
            if item == value:
                return True
            if item > value:
                return False

    def __next__(self):
        curr = self.mem[0]
        self.mem = self.mem[1], sum(self.mem)
        return curr

class Fibonacci(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return FibonacciIterator()

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in iter(self)
```

However there is another way to determine if a number is a Fibonacci number: If either `(5*n**2 + 4)` or `(5*n**2 – 4)` or both are perfect squares (square of an integer).

I'll use the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489519/5393381) to implement the `is_square` function:

```
def is_square(apositiveint):
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489519/5393381
    # Credit: Alex Martelli

    x = apositiveint // 2
    seen = {x}
    while x * x != apositiveint:
        x = (x + (apositiveint // x)) // 2
        if x in seen: 
            return False
        seen.add(x)
    return True

class FibonacciIterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem = [0, 1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __contains__(self, value):
        if value < self.mem[0]:
            return False
        else:
            # Just check if at least one of both is a perfect square
            value_squared_times_five = 5*value**2
            return is_square(value_squared_times_five + 4) or is_square(value_squared_times_five - 4)

    def __next__(self):
        curr = self.mem[0]
        self.mem = self.mem[1], sum(self.mem)
        return curr

class Fibonacci(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return FibonacciIterator()

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in iter(self)
```