# Math.sqrt giving floating values in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving this question:

> Given a positive integer num, write a function that returns True if
> num is a perfect square else False.
>
> Input: num = 16
>
> Output: true

My solution:

```
import math
class Solution:
    def isPerfectSquare(self, num: int) -> bool:
    
         return type(math.sqrt(16))=='int' //4.0=='int'
```

I know there are a lot of different solutions which are easier but I want to know how we can get this right as I can't use `int` to make it integer as 4.5 will also be the correct answer.

Comment: `x = math.sqrt(num); return round(x) == x`?

Comment: Your "solution" appears to be written _only_ for 16. It might as well just `return True`. You're completely ignoring `num`, which should be a hint that you're missing something.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd assume that's just for demonstration/testing/whatever and they'd actually use the `num` argument in the real code. Wouldn't be the first time I've seen something be hardcoded like that just to check something weird wasn't happening with the input value.

Comment: Or maybe `s = int(round(math.sqrt(num)))` and `return num == s*s`

Comment: Why use a class to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: What about `not bool(16**0.5 % 1)`?  No libraries and only 1 function call.

Comment: @Kemp or `int(x) == x` - probably the tiniest bit faster :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435/check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square

Comment: @Kemp based on the rest of it that doesn't seem like a safe assumption.

Comment: @Wolf `class Solution: ...` is the boilerplate used by some online grading platforms.

Comment: @AKX True enough, I was still thinking in math terms :)

Comment: It is worth noting that in python>=3.8, there is `math.isqrt` which computes the floor of the square root of any nonnegative integer (including integers too large for floating-point calculations)

Comment: Python code for `isqrt`, integer square root: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1562

Comment: thanks @Kemp for reminding me of round().

Comment: no @jonrsharpe, i am just taking an example of 16.

Comment: thanks, everyone for the answers...really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

`math.sqrt`'s default return type is float so you should check if the *square root* and *floor of square root* are equal or not to identify a perfect square...

This will work...

```
import math
class Solution:
    def isPerfectSquare(self, num: int) -> bool:
        sqroot = math.sqrt(num)
        return sqroot == math.floor(sqroot)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `==` with floats.  See [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). (Also, using `sqrt` as a variable name isn't a good idea.)

Comment: Better use `round(sqroot) ** 2 == num` and tell about the restriction of `num` to something around `2**26`

Comment: @Wolf thats also doable but the current solution will is faster. It wont matter in small numbers but in time of big numbers, it will be a problem..