# How to prevent Python from identifying a very large float as integer

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

What I would like to do in my program is to give the program a very large integer as an input, evaluate its square root, then determine if the square root is an integer. This determines whether the input is a square number. If it is, return the square root, if it is not, return `False`. My code looks something like this:

```
n = int(input())
sqrt = n**(1/2)
if sqrt.is_integer():
    return int(sqrt)
else:
    return False
```

However, this program is not working correctly with very, very large numbers. For example, when n = 170141183460469231731687303715884105727, the calculated square root value is 1.3043817825332783e+19, and sqrt.is_integer() returns True, when I know this number is a prime number and thus its square root cannot be an integer.

If Python cannot support an arbitrarily large float, is there a way to make Python only determine if the square root of an arbitrarily large integer has decimal places? Thanks in advance.

Btw, I have also tried `int(sqrt) == sqrt`. Same result.

Comment: IIRC, `float` can only encode about 2^64 different values.  `170141183460469231731687303715884105727` is not one of them. So `n`, in `n**(1/2)` is first rounded.  The result is not exactly encode-able either. so it get rounded to a nearby value which happens to be a whole number. It is not _arbitrarily large float,_ that is the issue, is insufficient precision.  Given the limited precision of `float`, **all** large `float` are integers.

Comment: This is an classic XY problem.  X: Title: "prevent Python from identifying a very large float as integer" and Y: "give the program a very large integer as an input, evaluate its square root, then determine if the square root is an integer".  The real goal is Y.  Solving X (or the inability to solve it) is not the real issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`math.isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt)? `math.isqrt(n)**2 == n` will tell you whether a nonnegative integer `n` is a square or not (without floating-point being involved at any point).

Comment: might be worth checking out Sympy as well; in this specific case [`sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square) seems to do what you want, but it does lots of other useful things

Comment: @MarkDickinson would you mind posting your solution as an answer? This math.isqrt() worked and I would like to mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kdwk: If the question is "how can I tell whether a Python `int` is a square", then that's a duplicate. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489540/270986