# How can I iterate (loop) over i, j values in order?

Tags: python, duplicates, pythagorean, triplet

I have this code to find Pythagorean triplets:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    for j in range(1,31):
        for k in range(1,31):
            if((i**2 + j**2)==(k**2)):
                print(i,",",j,",",k)
```

I get this result:

```
3 , 4 , 5
4 , 3 , 5
5 , 12 , 13
6 , 8 , 10
7 , 24 , 25
8 , 6 , 10
8 , 15 , 17
9 , 12 , 15
10 , 24 , 26
12 , 5 , 13
12 , 9 , 15
12 , 16 , 20
15 , 8 , 17
15 , 20 , 25
16 , 12 , 20
18 , 24 , 30
20 , 15 , 25
20 , 21 , 29
21 , 20 , 29
24 , 7 , 25
24 , 10 , 26
24 , 18 , 30
```

The problem is that the triplets are duplicated, because each `i, j` pair will be shown in either order. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I would advice using the formula for Pythagorian triples: `a = m**2 - n**2; b = 2*m*n; c = m**2 + n**2` for any two distinct integers `m, n`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Aside from solving the ordering problem, **it does not make sense** to loop over possible values for `k`; only one possible `k` value could ever possibly fit, for a given `i` and `j`. The real question is **whether** `(i ** 2) + (j ** 2)` is a square number; see [Check if a number is a perfect square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435).

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code, the repetition is caused by checking both `i²+j²` and `j²+i²`. Once we check for `i²+j²` it is no longer required to check the other one. So it's best to keep either of the variable be always greater than the other. That is, make the second loop starts from `i`.

The code after required changes:

```py
for i in range(1,31):
    for j in range(i,31):
        for k in range(1,31):
            if((i**2 + j**2)==(k**2)):
                print(i,",",j,",",k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The innermost loop (k) starts from `j+1`, therefore we are looking only at the values greater than `j`. this is enough to eliminate duplicates.

```
for i in range (1, 31):
    for j in range(i, 31):
        for k in range (j+1, 31):
            if ((i**2 + j**2) == (k**2)):
                print(i, ",", j, ",", k)
```

output:

```
3 , 4 , 5
5 , 12 , 13
6 , 8 , 10
7 , 24 , 25
8 , 15 , 17
9 , 12 , 15
10 , 24 , 26
12 , 16 , 20
15 , 20 , 25
18 , 24 , 30
20 , 21 , 29
```