Skipping certain values
I have some Python code that looks for perfect squares. But I know values it can skip, namely values of \$r\$, \$a\$ and \$b\$ that can be written in the following form (where \$n\$ is a postive integers):

$r=3n+2, a=3n^2-2, b=1-3n+3n^3$
$r=3n+17, a=73+30n+3n^2, b=361 + 222 n + 45 n^2 + 3 n^3$

So, these values can be skipped when running the code. But I do not know how to put that into my code.
The code I have now is the following:
import sympy as sp
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def is_perfect_square(expr):
    """ Check if the expression is a perfect square """
    sqrt_expr = sp.sqrt(expr)
    return sqrt_expr.is_integer or sqrt_expr == int(sqrt_expr)

def calculate_b(r, a):
    """ Calculate the value of b based on the given formula """
    expr = 3 * (3 * (-4 + r)**2 + 12 * a**2 * (-2 + r) - 4 * a * (-5 + r) * (-2 + r) + 4 * a**3 * (-2 + r)**2)
    b = (-12 + sp.sqrt(expr) + 3 * r) / (6 * (r - 2))
    return b

def monitor(r, a):
    """ Monitor function to print current values of r and a """
    print(f"Checking r = {r}, a = {a}")

def check_for_a_for_r(r, a_start=3):
    """ Main function to check conditions for a for a given r """
    local_results = []
    for a in range(a_start, 100000):
        expr = 3 * (3 * (-4 + r)**2 + 12 * a**2 * (-2 + r) - 4 * a * (-5 + r) * (-2 + r) + 4 * a**3 * (-2 + r)**2)

        monitor(r, a)

        if is_perfect_square(expr):
            b = calculate_b(r, a)

            if b.is_integer:
                local_results.append((r, a, b))
            else:
                print(f"Skipping: r = {r}, a = {a}, b = {b} (not an integer)")
    return local_results

def save_results(results):
    """ Save the results to a new text file with a unique filename """
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    file_path = os.path.join(script_directory, f"perfect_squares_{timestamp}.txt")

    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        if results:
            for r, a, b in results:
                file.write(f"r = {r}, a = {a}, b = {b}\n")
                print(f"Found perfect square: r = {r}, a = {a}, b = {b}")
        else:
            file.write("No perfect squares found.\n")

results = []
last_save_time = time.time()

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for r in range(3, 10**6 + 1):
        future = executor.submit(check_for_a_for_r, r, 3)  # Start 'a' at 3
        results.extend(future.result())

        if time.time() - last_save_time >= 3600:
            save_results(results)
            last_save_time = time.time()

save_results(results)

And it works but is really slow, so that's why I need to speed it up.
Maybe I can do something like this:
def check_additional_conditions(r, a, b):
    """ Check if the additional conditions are satisfied """
    # Condition 1: IntegerQ[(r-2)/3] == True
    condition1 = ((r - 2) / 3).is_integer
    
    # Condition 2: IntegerQ[Sqrt[(2 + a)/3]] == True
    condition2 = sp.sqrt((2 + a) / 3).is_integer
    
    # Condition 3: b = 1 - 3n + 3n^3 where n is a positive integer
    n = sp.Symbol('n', positive=True, integer=True)
    condition3 = sp.solve(1 - 3*n + 3*n**3 - b, n)
    condition3 = any([solution.is_integer and solution > 0 for solution in condition3])

    return condition1 and condition2 and condition3

But I do not see how I can implement this for the second case.

expr is calculated twice (in check_for_a_for_r and again in calculate_b)
Also few parts of this expr that are dependant from r can be precalculated as temporary variables before loop (but it's hard to say if it is worth optimizing)

What perfect squares are you looking for  ?
Normal perfect square can be found using only sqrt function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435/check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square

from sympy.ntheory.primetest import is_square: and then is_square(n) will tell you, using all of its methods, whether a integer n is square or not.

Not sure if this will be helpful in your case, sympy has something called lambdify that allows to speed-up some computations.  I have no sympy experience, just searched for sympy+vectorization.
