# In C (Linux) how will I be able to find out whether squareroot(n) = Integer

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

In C (linux) how will I be able to find out if the squareroot of a number is and integer or a floating point.
I want to write a program using a function pointer which adds up all the Perfect squares
upto the limit sepcified.

Comment: There's no *floating point integer*. It's either an integer or floating point.

Comment: Why not, instead, calculate the square of the integers and sum those instead of trying to find out if the square root is an integer?

Comment: True sum all integers^2  < sqrt(limit). That would work better

Comment: Another thing you could do, assuming you're running on a CPU which uses IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic (which is most modern CPUs), you could write some code to extract all data you need from the float and determine whether or not there are any bits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @George - Yes, the average programmer who talks about floating point integers (see the question pre-edit) is going to be able to figure out how to do that (much less whether or not h(is/er) implementation uses IEEE-754 floating point at all) in a short period of time.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Compile it with `-lm` on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int checkRoot(double n) {
    long n_sqrt = (long)(sqrt(n)+0.5);
    return n_sqrt*n_sqrt == n;
}

int main() {
    double n = 9.0;
    if(checkRoot(n)) {
        puts("Perfect root.");
    }
    else {
        puts("Not quite.");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[You should also read this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Comment: Thankyou. :) This works but please explain. long n_sqrt = (long)(sqrt(n)+0.5); return n_sqrt*n_sqrt == n;

Comment: @Pavitar For example, if `sqrt(9)` gives 2.999999 instead of 3.0, rounding it up would clear that. However, on my processor it seems to calculate it correctly even without the round-up. The return value is simple, as if the squared number to the power of 2 isn't the original number, then it returns 0 (FALSE). If it is, then the return value is 1 (TRUE) and the number is a perfect root.

Comment: The `+0.5` is unnecessary on any platform whose arithmetic conforms to the IEEE-754 standard (which is most platforms, including the questioner's ubuntu/x86)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look up the paper [what every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg and rethink your question.

Answer (score 2):

Not really the answer you are looking for, but I think it is much better to simply sum up the squares of integers which fall into the range than try to use `sqrt` to determine whether a number is a perfect square (As suggested in some of the comments to the question). This avoids having to use floating point values, which makes it a lot more reliable as a general purpose solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long sum_squares(int limit){
    int i;
    long long ret=0;
    for (i=1;i*i<=limit;i++){
        ret+=i*i;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    printf("%lld\n",sum_squares(10));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float root = sqrt(number);
int int_root = (int) root;
if ( (root / (float)int_root) == 1.0f ) return "is integer";
```

That might work. Optimise it a bit.

or

```
float root;
if ((root % (int)root) == 0) { return "is integer";)
```

A simpler solution

```
int SUM_PERFECT_SQUARES (int limit) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < floor(sqrt(limit)); i++) {
        sum += i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Newton-Ralphson method to implement square root for integers yourself.  But, for the problem you're talking about, I would recommend calculating the squares of all the integers instead.

```
/* Returns the greatest integer that's <= to the square root. */
unsigned int isqrt(unsigned int x)
{
    if (x < 4) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        unsigned int try = x / 2;
        while ((x / try) < try) {
            try = (try + (x / try)) / 2;
        }
        return try;
    }
}

int check_perfect_square(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int sqrt = isqrt(x);
    return (sqrt * sqrt) == x;
}
```

And, for my actual suggested solution:

```
unsigned int sum_perfect_squares(unsigned int limit)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned int i = 1;
    for (i = 1; i * i < limit; ++i) {
        sum += i * i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical nit: Assuming your `n` is an integer, the square root is never a floating point number. It's either an integer (in the case of perfect squares) or an irrational number (which cannot be represented at all except with special symbolic-math libraries).