# Is binary search in an array access faster than using a hash table?

Tags: c++, optimization

On [this website](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C++/General_optimization_techniques/Other_techniques), section 4.4, it is suggested to binary search an array rather than using a hash table. How is that?

Comment: Right below the suggestion, it says *"A binary search on an array has logarithmic complexity, like search trees, but has the advantage of compactness and locality of reference typical of arrays."*

Comment: Probably depends on how many buckets are in the hash table, and the efficiency of the hashing algorithm involved.  I doubt you can make a blanket statement that one is faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are too many factors to make a blanket statement.

- The number of elements in the container.
- The speed of the hash function.
- The speed of the comparison function.
- The number of hash collisions.

Comment: +1.  For small arrays, both binary and hash searches may have more overhead than a simple linear search.

Answer (score 3):

Hashtables (with good hash functions) have O(1) complexity (which is better than O(log n) ;), since they directly "link you to" the result.

But using hashtables for small sets of data/arrays might not be worth the overhead of allocating the memory needed for the table.

Comment: This is flawed. We are talking about lookup tables here, so talking about computational complexity is simply not right.

Comment: @nightcracker what? It seems relevant to me. Looking up an element in an array using binary search vs a hash table is what the question is about no?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: for small N (for example 0 < N < 2^32) solutions with O(1) and log(N) complexity compete very much, because the hidden constants dominate. Take for example the binary search I wrote in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296669/565635

Comment: @nightcracker I realise that and completely agree with you, but that doesn't mean that talking about computational complexity is completely not germane to this question.

Comment: @nightcracker:  For lookup tables, nothing beats a random access array, if possible.  A map container may be more efficient, or even a hashmap.