# Finding the floor of square root without using sqrt function

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say I have an integer `n` and I want to find the largest number `m` for which the square of that number is smaller than `n`.

What would be the optimal solution for this problem?

Comment: Start by doing some research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to get the integer part of sqrt(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930307/fastest-way-to-get-the-integer-part-of-sqrtn)

Comment: is m an integer also?

Comment: Your title answers the question already. Include the <math> library and use the sqrt function, then cast that from a double to an int. If you use a float, you may face inaccuracy problems when dealing with larger numbers.

Comment: I cannot do cast from sqrt. I am not allowed to use sqrt.

Comment: Oh, damn, my bad. I read that without as while. Derp.
In that case, I agree with Marc. (Unless you shouldn't be using sqrt in the sense that you should be avoiding Square Roots for the solution completely).

Comment: Use the "Babylonian Method" which is basicaly an application of the Newton-Raphson method. The link was posted by Marc B.

Comment: The Babylonian method is really not what he needs. It is used to find the square root, which is not what he wants. He just wants to find the floor of the square root. A simple search on integers will be perfect. You start with some number with half of the digits of your number, and you square it. If it's bigger than your number, you try smaller, and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure why this question was "closed as not a real question" and why  double squeeze says Babylonian method is not applicable. The question and answer were exactly what I was looking for.  I read this question as being same as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930307/fastest-way-to-get-the-integer-part-of-sqrtn which has other good answers as well.

Answer (score 9):

"The Optimal Solution" rarely exists, but a reasonably fast algorithm is as follows (<s>anyone knows its name?</s>), it's called the Babylonian Method:

```
int num = 4567;

int r1 = num / 2;
int r2 = 2;

while (std::abs(r2 - r1) > 1) {
     r2 = (r1 + r2) / 2;
     r1 = num / r2;
}
```

Here `r1` and `r2` are the lower and higher approximations of the square root. In your case, you'll need the smaller one.

Comment: That's the "Babylonian Method"

Comment: `int int_abs(int x)` Er ... whats wrong with `std::abs` (always assuming the OP is using a compiler that supports it)?

Comment: @dmckee I'm going to RTFM, but doesn't that take `float`s?

Comment: @dmckee I read the FM, and I found out it's overloaded. Sorry. (I wrote this code as C...)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just looking for the integer part, you could do it this way:

1. Start a loop with the lowest possible m, ie m=1 ( unless you're allowing n < 1 )
2. Check if m*m is greater than n
3. If it's not, you need to check the next m, so add 1 to m and go on to the next iteration of the loop
4. If it is bigger, then stop looping and subtract 1 from m, because m-1 was the final value to be smaller than the square root of n.

```
int n = 123; //or whatever you want
int m = 1;
while (m * m <= n) {
    m = m + 1;
}
return (m - 1);
```

Comment: Yea... It's at least valid. But I have no problem admitting your solution is better.

Comment: @johnhopkins of course this is fine for small values of `n`.

Comment: An easy optimisation should be to turn this into a binary-search-like algorithm, but H2CO3's solution is probably still faster.

Comment: @Dukeling I really like that idea. Might try it later.