# android the return type is incompatible with Thread.getState()

Tags: android

I am following an example about bluetooth in Android. When following the example and trying to understand the process, I get an error: "The return type is incomatible with Thread.getState()".  What causes this error and how can I resolve it?

Here is the relevant code:

```
private int mState;
  /**
   * Set the current state of the chat connection
   * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
   */
  private synchronized void setState(int state) {
      if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
      mState = state;

      // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
      mHandler.obtainMessage(Rc_auto.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
  }

  /**
   * Return the current connection state. */
  public synchronized int getState() {
      return mState;
  }

  //How it's called
  public synchronized void start() {
      setState(STATE_LISTEN);
  }
```

Comment: In your current code you should be returning a `synchronized int` but you are only returning an `int`. Remove `synchronized`.

Comment: What is a synchronized int...? `synchronized` applies to the method, not to the return type.

Comment: Is it possible that you added `extends Thread` to a class that was working before? Because then there is a conflict with a [method of the same name](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()) in class `Thread`

Comment: I removed extends Thread and the errors are gone thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given in the comments below my question.

I just had to remove 'extends Thread' at the begin of the class.

All of you your help was helpful and I learned something extra.

Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 3):

You should probably rename `getState()` to something else (like getConnectionState) because your method overrides [`Thread.getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29), and I guess that's not what you intended.