# Is the a name for redifining a class in main()? What is the merit in such use?

Tags: java, oop

I was reading an example about `final` for Java, and saw something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547663/java-final-method-what-promises-it):

```
Counter c = new Counter()
{
  public int count() {
    super.count();   
    return super.count();
  }
}
c.count(); // now count 2
```

Is there a name for such construct? Is this ever used in practice? Is yes, it is considered a good OOD? A reference or a blog article would be appreciated.

Comment: is [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) what you are talking about?

Comment: Its a commonly used hack(?) for passing functions to other functions, but can also be used as you show to make subclasses which are used only once

Comment: Thanks Karthik. This is indeed called an anonymous class and its uses are outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java). Thanks again. Marking this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack.

Comment: @Forethinker First time I have seen somebody agreeing that a question is duplicate. Good Job mate :)