# Find all perfect squares that are a permutation of some 300 digits

Tags: algorithm, permutation

This was a question that was asked to my friend in a Google interview a while back. He was unable to come up with a solution but ended up bagging the job anyway. Here's the question

> You have been given 300 digits comprising of 100 ones, 100 twos, and 100 threes, now come up with an algorithm that will determine all such numbers which are a perfect square

I tried this for a while but am stumped. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: Must each answer use all of the provided digits, or any subset?

Comment: I would think it implied that the numbers all have 300 digits.

Comment: @cheeken all the 300 digits need to be used for each answer.

Comment: Wow. If we pretend that this isn't a trick question, even just checking whether or not a 300 digit number is a square is a huge problem on its own [(SO discussion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer).
On top of that, you would probably need to test an absurd number of permutations.

Comment: @Queequeg: Which is the first clue that there is a trick.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
   printf ("{}\n");
```

The set in question is empty (the sum of the digits is divisible by 3 but not by 9).

Comment: To anyone who doesn't understand why: If the sum of the digits is divisible by 3, the number is divisible by 3. Same applies to 9. Since the sum of the digits is divisible by 3 but not 9, the number is a multiple of 3 but not 9. A perfect square can't have exactly one factor of 3.

Answer (score 0):

n.m's answer is of course great.

It is also easy to see that the only number that can have its square have last digit among {1,2,3} is a number starting with unit digit as 9. Now, if we use 9 as the last digit of a number that would square to one of the combinations, we will soon see that there is  no 10's digit along with 9 at unit digit that can give a number involving {1,2,3} in the 10th digit of its square.

Probably, this explanation answers a question like "does any combination of 300 digits with 1,2 and 3 have a square root"?