# How to force a C program to print an unexpected result?

Tags: c, linux

The source code of `square.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int square(int *ptr)
{
  int a;
  a = *ptr;
  return a * a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int a, aa;
  srandom(time(NULL));
  a = random() % 10 + 1;
  aa = square(&a);
  printf("%d\n", aa);
  return 0;
}
```

The command-line to compile the source code is:

```
gcc square.c -o square
```

Is it possible to run the `square` executable in Linux so that the printed value will **not** be a square of any integer number?

**Any** method of running the program is allowed.

Comment: homework? job interview? please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a correct program and then try to get an unexpected output from it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I guess you could run it through a debugger, brake and change the value of aa before it prints.

Comment: Seems to me that this is off-topic, being about how to run a program rather than how to do programming. Even if you stretch things and fit it in as part of a shell script, that just seems to shift it from "off topic" to "not productive".

Comment: change libc.  hexedit the binary.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. We can override printf.

Write the code in your post into square.c and compile it with `gcc square.c`

Make this file, fakesquare.c

```
int printf(char *str,int i)
{
    return puts("7");
}
```

Compile fakesquare.c as a shared library:

```
gcc -fPIC -o libfakesquare.so -shared fakesquare.c
```

Run the square program with libfakesquare.so preloaded:

```
[15:27:27 0 /tmp] $ LD_PRELOAD=./libfakesqare.so ./a.out
7
[15:29:16 0 /tmp] $ LD_PRELOAD=./libfakesqare.so ./a.out
7
[15:29:16 0 /tmp] $ LD_PRELOAD=./libfakesqare.so ./a.out
7
```

Witout libfakeshared.so preloaded:

```
[15:29:40 0 /tmp] $  ./a.out
36
[15:29:41 0 /tmp] $  ./a.out
16
[15:29:42 0 /tmp] $  ./a.out
64
```

Answer (score 0):

The only dependency at your code is libc. If libc stays unmodified then your code will always work.

Also your program will fail if before running it, all available memory is exhausted. You can always check if ptr!=NULL.

Comment: I don't see how random() returning 0 should make square() fail.

Comment: the square of 0 is 0. However running ./a.out will always print 0, thereafter we don't have a program that prints a _random_ square. The output will be _constant_

Comment: The code is `a = random() % 10 + 1`, so a would be 1 and the output would be 1. Besides that, the original question was if the program might in any run print a value that is not the square of an integer number. 0 and 1 are the square of an integer number. (Of course you are right that the program might not do what it is intended to do.)

Comment: sure no problem. I wanted to emphasize that modifying libc.so somehow it might result to wrong square.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

[Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Their code seems optimized, but whichever is simplest should do the trick for you.

Comment: That is completely besides the point. OP doesn't want to find out whether a number is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a standard C environment I don't see a reason why this should fail on a standard platform. The code might fail if `printf` is not doing what it is inteded to do, but probably this is not what you are asking for. It also might fail on a platform where `int` is as small as a byte and a byte is only 6 bits wide. In this case your square function might calculate 9*9=81 which will not fit in the result type `int` (0..63 for 6 bit-byte). But in my opinion this is a quite academic case.