# How do I make this code work for large input values?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k,t;
    long int n;
    int count;
    int a,b;
    float c;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(k=0;k<t;k++)
    {
        count=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {

            a=pow(i,2);
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                b=pow(j,2);
                c=sqrt(a+b);
                if((c-floor(c)==0)&&c<=n)
                ++count;


            }


        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above is a c code that counts the number of Pythagorean triplets within range `1..n`.
How do I optimize it ? It times out for large input .
1<=T<=100
1<=N<=10^6

Comment: What is "large input values"? 1000? 100000000000000000?

Comment: What do you define as a "large input"? Without this information, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: What do you mean it "times out"? Compiled C code doesn't have a time limit, it will happily burn up CPU cycles until you stop the process.

Comment: scanf("%d",&t);  // what is t here

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Information that the OP should have given: there is some sort of programming challenge on the Internet that will evaluate solutions by timing them, and asks this specific questions, and the OP is trying to improve their results in this challenge.

Comment: @Uday: It's an `int`... From `int i,j,k,t;`

Comment: from wikipedia: 'If (a, b, c) is a Pythagorean triple, then so is (ka, kb, kc) for any positive integer k.'

So you probably do not have to iterate all the way through n.

Comment: @Sani ,i believe he is asking what is the inputted value

Comment: Don't use `pow`, use i*i instead. And you don't need sqrt to check this. Simple multiplications like `if (a*a + b*b == c*c)` is much faster than sqrt. But nobody has enough information to answer this until you answer the above questions

Comment: I added the input constraints on my last edit . 1<=t<=100 and 1<=n<=10^6 .

Comment: @CoolGuy: Then he should have asked what the *value* of `t` is. `t` is an `int`. That's the answer to his question.

Comment: Using `float c;` is likely a false economy here.  Recommend `double c`.  Either that or use `sqrf()` and floorf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner two loops are O(n*n) so there's not too much that can be done without changing algorithms. Just looking at the inner loop the best I could come up with in a short time was the following:

```
unsigned long long int i,j,k,t;
unsigned long long int n = 30000;  //Example for testing
unsigned long long int count = 0;
unsigned long long int a, b;
unsigned long long int c;
unsigned long long int n2 = n * n;

for(i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    a = i*i;

    for(j=i; j<n; j++)
    {
        b = j*j;

        unsigned long long int sum = a + b;
        if (sum > n2) break;

              // Check for multiples of 2, 3, and 5
        if ( (sum & 2) || ((sum & 7) == 5) || ((sum & 11) == 8) ) continue;

        c = sqrt((double)sum);
        if (c*c == sum) ++count;
    }
}
```

A few comments:

- For the case of n=30000 this is roughly twice as fast as your original.
- If you don't mind n being limited to 65535 you can switch to `unsigned int` to get a x2 speed increase (or roughly x4 faster than your original).
- The check for multiples of 2/3/5 increases the speed by a factor of two. You may be able to increase this by looking at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer).
- Your original code has integer overflows when `i > 65535` which is the reason I switched to 64-bit integers for everything.
- I think your method of checking for a perfect square doesn't always work due to the inherent in-precision of floating point numbers. The method in my example should get around that and is slightly faster anyways.
- You are still bound to the O(n*n) algorithm. On my machine the code for n=30000 runs in about 6 seconds which means the n=1000000 case will take close to 2 hours. Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) shows a host of other algorithms you could explore.

Comment: Please detail how `if ( (sum & 2) || ((sum & 7) == 5) || ((sum & 11) == 8) )` is a "Check for multiples of 2, 3, and 5".  It looks more like a check for "last hex digit of a perfect square must be 0, 1, 4, or 9."  I think the 2,3,5 comment refers to now deleted code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the benchmark is that you are expecting.

But for now, the power function could be a bottle neck in this. I think you can do either of the two things:

a) precalculate and save in a file and then load into a dictionary all the squared values. Depending on the input size, that might be loading your memory.

b) memorize previously calculated squared values so that when asked again, you could reuse it there by saving CPU time. This again, would eventually load your memory.

Comment: Of course, using a simple multiplication would be the simplest solution. The overhead of `pow(i, 2)` over `i*i` or `(double)i * (double)i` is tremendous.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your indexes as (unsigned) long or even (unsigned) long long, but you may have to use big num libraries to solve your problem for huge numbers. Using unsigned uppers your Max number limit but forces you to work with positive numbers. I doubt you'll need bigger than long long though.
It seems your question is about optimising your code to make it faster. If you read up on Pythagorean triplets you will see there is a way to calculate them using integer parameters. If 3 4 5 are triplets then we know that 2*3 2*4 2*5 are also triplets and k*3 k*4 k*5 are also triplets. Your algorithm is checking all of those triplets. There are better algorithms to use, but I'm afraid you will have to search on Google to study about Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: The question is about the time the program takes, not about generalization to larger inputs.