# Optimized way to find if a number is a perfect square

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I had a question in my assignment to find whether a number was [perfect square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_square) or not:

> Perfect square is an element of algebraic structure which is equal to
>   the square of another element.

For example: 4, 9, 16 etc.

What my friends did is, if `n` is the number, they looped `n - 1` times calculating `n * n`:

```
// just a general gist
int is_square = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
{
  if ((i * i) == n)
  {
    std::cout << "Yes , it is";
    is_square = 1;
    break;
  }
}
if (is_square == 0)
{
  std::cout << "No, it is not";
}
```

I came up with a solution as shown below:

```
 if (ceil(sqrt(n)) == floor(sqrt(n)))
 {
   std::cout << "Yes , it is";
 }
 else
 {
   std::cout << "no , it is not";
 }
```

And it works properly.

Can it be called as ***more optimized solution*** than others?

Comment: Although a Java question, the algorithms should also be applicable in C++ (and the accepted answer uses C++): [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Comment: in addition to all the other answers, there's a bunch of tricks you can use to right away eliminate cases. For example, all squares end in 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 and 00.

Comment: I do not think your solution is 100% fool proof. It might be that sqrt(k*k) returns a number that is slightly less than k (k-epsilon), and then floor will be different from ceil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tried and true remains:

```
double sqrt(double x); // from lib

bool is_sqr(long n) {
    long root = sqrt(n);
    return root * root == n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to know the complexity of the sqrt(x) function on your computer to compare it against other methods. By the way, you are calling sqrt(n) twice ; consider storing it into a variable (even if the compiler probably does this for you).

If using something like Newton's method, the complexity of sqrt(x) is in `O(M(d))` where M(d) measures the time required to multiply two d-digits numbers. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

Your friend's method does (n - 2) multiplications (worst case scenario), thus its complexity is like `O(n * M(x))` where x is a growing number.

Your version only uses sqrt() (ceil and floor can be ignored because of their constant complexity), which makes it `O(M(n))`.

`O(M(n)) < O(n * M(x))` - Your version is more optimized than your friend's, but is not the most efficient. Have a look at interjay's link for a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what limitations do you have but perfect square number definition is clear

> Another way of saying that a (non-negative) number is a square number,
>   is that its square roots are again integers
>   [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number)

```
IF SQRT(n) == FLOOR(SQRT(n)) THEN
    WRITE "Yes it is"
ELSE
    WRITE "No it isn't"
```

examples [sqrt(9) == floor(sqrt(9))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%289%29+%3D%3D+floor%28sqrt%289%29%29), [sqrt(10) == floor(sqrt(10))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%2810%29+%3D%3D+floor%28sqrt%2810%29%29)

Comment: Isn't SQRT(n) == FLOOR(N) only true if n is 1 or 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void isPerfect(int n){
    int ctr=0,i=1;
    while(n>0){
        n-=i;
        i+=2;
        ctr++;
    }
    if(!n)cout<<"\nSquare root = "<<ctr;
    else cout<<"\nNot a perfect square";
}
int main() {
    isPerfect(3);
    isPerfect(2025);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend this one

```
if(((unsigned long long)sqrt(Number))%1==0) // sqrt() from math library
{
   //Code goes Here
}
```

It works because.... all Integers( & only positive integers ) are positive multiples of 1

and Hence the solution.....

You can also run a benchmark Test like;
I did with following code in MSVC 2012

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void IsPerfect(unsigned long long Number);

void main()
{
    clock_t Initial,Final;
    unsigned long long Counter=0;
    unsigned long long Start=Counter;
    Start--;
    cout<<Start<<endl;
    Initial=clock();
    for( Counter=0 ; Counter<=100000000 ; Counter++ )
    {
        IsPerfect( Counter );
    }
    Final=clock();
    float Time((float)Final-(float)Initial);
    cout<<"Calculations Done in "<< Time ;
    getch();
}

void IsPerfect( unsigned long long Number)
{
    if(ceil(sqrt(Number)) == floor(sqrt(Number)))
    //if(((unsigned long long)sqrt(Number))%1==0) // sqrt() from math library
    {
    }

}
```

Your code took 13590 time units

Mine just 10049 time units

Moreover I'm using few extra steps that is Type conversion

like

```
(unsigned long long)sqrt(Number))
```

Without this it can do still better

I hope it helps .....

Have a nice day....

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions is more optimized, but it may not work. Since `sqrt(x)` may return the *true square root +/- epsilon*,  3 different roots must be tested:

```
bool isPerfect(long x){
  double k = round( sqrt(x) );

  return (n==(k-1)*(k-1)) || (n==k*k) || (n==(k+1)*(k+1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple python code for finding perfect square r not:

```
import math
n=(int)(input())
giv=(str)(math.sqrt(n))
if(len(giv.split('.')[1])==1):
    print  ("yes")
else:
    print ("No")
```