# Iterating over a large list

Tags: python

I have a list in the range [465868129, 988379794] both inclusive. When I use the following code I get a Memory Error. What can I do?

```
r = [465868129, 988379794]
list = [x for x in xrange(r[0], r[1]+1)]
```

Comment: What are you going to do with that list?

Comment: What you are going to do is important because answers like _use a lazy iterable_ seem like the right way to go, but we can't be sure.

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm going to count the number of square integers between that range.

Comment: You really want to avoid creating that huge `list = [x for x in xrange(r[0], r[1]+1)]`. It will have 500million entries.

Comment: @ChrisD right, so don't create a huge list. Just use the xrange, which is lazy.

Comment: @ChrisD: you can directly take the length of an iterable!

Comment: @smci - I don't understand... you can only take the length of an iterable by iterating. Some iterables like `itertools.cycle` are infinite and only Chuck Norris can take the size of them.

Comment: @tdelaney if you _know_ it's infinite, you don't need to take the size. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the `xrange` directly instead of creating a list.

```
for x in xrange(r[0], r[1] + 1):
    ...
```

But iterating over such a large range is a very, very slow way to find squares. The fact that you run out of memory should alert you that a different approach is needed.

A much better way would be to take the square roots of each end point and then **iterate between the square roots**. Each integer between the square roots, when squared, would give you one of the numbers you're searching for.

In fact, if you're clever enough, you can generate all the squares with a single list comprehension and avoid an explicit `for` loop entirely.

Comment: List comprehension? Technically, OP said he wanted to _count_ the squares, so you don't even need a list comprehension. Just some arithmetic. But I suspect this is a HW question, and perhaps there is yet some arbitrary constraint against _not_ using lists. :/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very good reason to store the list items in a list, iterate over the generator instead, that way Python won't need to allocate a lot of memory (causing your Memory Error) to create that list:

```
init, end = (465868129, 988379794)
items = xrange(init, end + 1)

for item in items:
    #Do something with item
```

To count squares on an arbitrary range consider the following formula:

```
import math

number_of_squares = int(math.sqrt(end) - math.sqrt(init)) + 
                    op(is_perfect_square(init), is_perfect_square(end))
```

The `is_perfect_square(n)` is another problem on its own, so check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer) if interested.

The `op` is used to adjust the number of squares when the init and end of the intervals `init (or/and/neither) end` are perfect squares. So we need a function with the following characteristics:

- Both numbers are perfect squares: Eg: 25,64 => 8 - 5 = 3 (and there are 4 squares on that range). (it should sum 1 more)
- End is a perfect square: Eg: 26,64 => 8 - 5 = 3 (There are 3 squares on that range).  (it is correct => it should sum 0)
- Init is a perfect square: Eg: 25,65 => 8 - 5 = 3 (There are 4 squares on that range). (it should sum 1 more)
- None of the numbers are primes: Eg: 26, 65 => 8 - 5 = 3 (There are 3 squares on that range) (it is correct => it should sum 0)

So we need an operator with the following characteristics, based on the past examples:

- **1 op 1 = 1** (Both numbers are perfect squares)
- **0 op 1 = 0** (End is a perfect square)
- **1 op 0 = 1** (Init is a perfect square)
- **0 op 0 = 0** (None of the numbers are perfect squares)

Note that the `max` function almost fulfils our needs, but it fails on the second case max(0,1) = 1 and it should be 0.

So, looks like the result only depends on the first operator: if it's one, the result is 1, on the other hand if it's 0, it returns 0.

So, it's easy to write the function with that in mind:

```
import math

number_of_squares = int(math.sqrt(end) - math.sqrt(init)) + 
                    int(is_perfect_square(init))
```

Thanks to @kojiro, we have this approach (having a similar idea), which is easier to read:

```
from math import sqrt, floor, ceil

number_of_squares = 1 + floor(sqrt(end)) - ceil(sqrt(init))
```

Comment: This is as close to _the right way_ as I think we can get assuming that we _have to iterate_, for some reason, to count squares.

Comment: I'm confused by your using `max` on the `int` of booleans. Couldn't you just do `or`?

Comment: For that matter, what's wrong with just `floor(sqrt(end)) - ceil(sqrt(init))`?

Comment: @kojiro The floor and ceil approach does not work if the numbers are both perfect squares (I tried using 1,100), also if none of the numbers are prime (like 2,99) it does not work.

Comment: @avenet You're right, but you still don't need the `is_perfect_square`. I was just off-by-one. Consider `1 + floor(sqrt(end)) - ceil(sqrt(init))`. It works whether the bounds are perfect squares or not, because `ceil(n) == floor(n)` iff `n` is a whole number.

Comment: @kojiro You are right (on the previous time we needed to sum 1 to it), I encourage you to create an answer with your formula. I'd be happy to vote it up. If you don't want I will edit this answer and credit it to you. Thank you for sharing your approach, it's simpler than mine!!

Comment: Feel free to use my comment in your answer. It's all Creative Commons anyway. :)