# For each member of a sequence, determine if it is a perfect square

Tags: java, math, optimization, perfect-square

What I'm asking about is not a duplicate of [this very popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295579/581205). For a randomly chosen input, some quick tests can be done and if they fail to say "not a square", some computation of the square root has to be done (I myself tried a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686659/581205), too).

When the numbers to be tested come from a simple sequence, the situation differs, as it's possible to use the previous (approximate) square root. For a trivial sequence it's trivial as well, e.g.,

```
long sqrt = 1;
for (long i=1; i<limit; ++i) {
   if (sqrt*sqrt == i) {
       handleSquare(i);
       ++sqrt;
   }
}
```

My question is what can be done for more complicated sequences like

```
x[i] = start + i*i;
```

or

```
x[i] = start - i*i*i;
```

I'm thinking about Newton's method, but I can't see how to make it fast (as division is a pretty expensive operation).

Comment: I think that your "trivial" example is a little *too* trivial.  Think of it from this angle:  the square root of a number that is a perfect square is rational; that is, there is no decimal component to the number.

Comment: @Makoto Right, it's too trivial as everybody would instead loop over `sqrt`. But forget it, the idea is that *keeping some  information* between iterations helps.

Answer (score 0):

To what kind of sequence would you like to apply your algorithm ? Below is a solution that should work well when x[i] diverges but not too fast.

For instance if

```
x[i] = a*i^p + o(i^p)
```

and that i is large enough then you will have

```
x[i+1]-x[i] ~ p * a * i^{p-1}.
```

If y[i] denotes the largest integer such that

```
y[i]^2 <= x[i]
```

then you have

```
y[i] ~ sqrt(a) i^{p/2}
```

and

```
y[i+1]-y[i] ~ 1/(2 y[i]) * (x[i+1]-x[i]) ~ p/2 * sqrt(a) i^{p/2-1}
```

So you can take this as a guess for y[i+1] and then update to the correct value, which should save you some iterations.

In general you can always use the formula

```
y[i+1]-y[i] ~ 1/(2 y[i]) * (x[i+1]-x[i])
```

as a guess but this will be useful only if x[i+1]-x[i] is small with respect to y[i]^2 -- ie, with respect to x[i]. It may also be worth improving a bit on the formula using the (exact) second order expansion of

```
y[i+1]^2 = y[i]^2 + 2y[i](y[i+1]-y[i]) + (y[i+1]-y[i])^2
```

in order to improve the guess of y[i+1].

Note that this won't work well if x[i] remains bounded when i is large or if x diverges exponentially fast.