# square numbers Java

Tags: java, square-root

"An array is used to store ten integer numbers. Write a Java program that determines and print the square numbers which are also odd numbers from the given array."

The problem I have is how to figure out if the number in the array is a square number. I tried this way but it's not correct!

```
import java.math.*;
public class JavaApplication43 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] no = {22, 44, 25, 89, 81, 55, 23, 25, 55};

        for (int i = 0; i < no.length; i++) {

            int x = no[i];
            double y;
            if (x % 2 != 0) {
                y = Math.sqrt(x);
                if (x == (Math.pow(y, 2))) 
                    System.out.println(no[i]);
            }
       }
   }
}
```

This is the output it gives me

```
run:
25
81
55
25
55
```

`55` is there too that means this method I used is not successful!

Comment: I guess you mean the numbers must be squares of integers only since every positive number is a square of some real number. Hence you could check whether `y` is an integer (i.e. the fraction part is 0 or at least very small because of precision issues).

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < no.length; i++) {
    int x = no[i];
    if (x % 2 == 0) continue;
    int y = (int) Math.sqrt(x);
    if (x == y * y) { 
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't he eliminate even numbers if that's a requirement?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, for example? :)

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov the number would have to be large, larger than you can get in an `int` value come to think of it. ;)

Comment: but using integers in the array

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov due to precision issues you could get a fraction of `.99999999` instead of the next higher integer and trunction would thus result in the wrong value.

Comment: @laish129 the square root of an integer in most cases is still a double though.

Answer (score 5):

You can determine if a number is a square by checking if its square root is an integer.

```
double sqrt = Math.sqrt(x);
long sqrt2 = Math.round(sqrt);
if (Math.abs(sqrt - sqrt2) / sqrt < 1e-15)
   // we have a square.
```

If you know `x` is an `int` you shouldn't get a rounding error and you can do

```
int x = ...
double sqrt = Math.sqrt(x);
if ((int) sqrt == sqrt)
    // we have a square.
```

Comment: This pattern can be used to the limits of `double` precision although `int` won't test those limits.

Answer (score 2):

hope this will be much easier,

```
    if((arr[i]%2 != 0) & (Math.sqrt(arr[i])%1 == 0)){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

In here inside if condition first I check whether number is an odd number by taking modulus division and the 2nd condition check whether number is a perfect square. First I get the square root of given number and then take the modulus division by 1 and check whether it's equal to 0. If number is a perfect square, square root of that number is an integer, when I take the modulus division of an integer answer should be equal to 0.