# Clpfd not a square number

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Is it possible to make a constraint for an integer to say it can not be a (Perfect) square number?

I have:

```
square(Square):- N#>0, Square #= N*N.
```

How do I define `notsquare(Notsquare):- ...`

My first thought was to have `P*P =Q*Q*Notsquare` and `Remainder #>0, Remainder #= P rem Q.`

But P and Q need to be able to be non integers so this didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
notSquare(S):- N #> 0, R #>0, R #< 2*N+1, S #= N*N+R.
```

?

Should work if `S > 0`; if you need to work with negative numbers too, I suppose you could modify it as

```
notSquare(S):- S #> 0, N #> 0, R #>0, R #< 2*N+1, S #= N*N+R.
notSquare(S):- S #< 0, SM #= -S, notSquare(SM).
```

Comment: @user27815 - modified my answer to consider the negative number (`S < 0`) case

Comment: Wow, very nice! And it would be still greater if the last two clauses you show also worked for example for the most general query and others like it. Try for example: `?- notSquare(N).` The solution is simple: Use CLP(FD) constraints for more generality!

Comment: Its interesting to compare this slight variant `square_t(Square,T):-N#>=0,Square #=N*N, T=true.
square_t(S,T):-N #> 0, R #>0, R #< 2*N+1, S #= N*N+R, T=false.` 
to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer - it is fast and simple!

Comment: And more general! You can pull the `T=true` and `T=false` unifications into the clause heads. Note by the way that you can use bitwise operations too in CLP(FD) as provided by SWI.

Comment: @mat - Do you mean that `S > 0` should be `S #> 0` and that `S < 0` should be `S #< 0`? Modified my answer in this way. Ps. thanks for your help: my first answer was a disaster; I even didn't know that gprolog support something equivalent to clpfd.

Comment: And prob change the `is` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, to **all** of your points! Forget `(is)/2`, use `(#=)/2` **instead** for integer arithmetic! Easy to teach, easy to learn, easy to use. And yes, you are right about your first answer, and I am happy that you figured this out yourself. In such cases, telling the truth to others would invariably seem extremely condescending ;-) GNU Prolog is a nice case where CLP(FD) constraints are available right out of the box, which is also the case for example in B-Prolog. I recommend to configure other systems in the same way, so that CLP(FD) constraints are readily available in all programs.

Comment: Try `member(N,[5,10,17,26,37]), notSquare(N).`

Comment: @false - with `main :- member(N,[5,10,16,17,25,26,36,37]), notSquare(N), write(N), write(' '), fail, halt(0).` I obtain `5 10 17 26 37`; this is bad?

Comment: @max66: That's pointless.  Use the toplevel and look at the particular answers.

Comment: @false what is the problem?

Comment: @user27815: `between(0,40, N), call_residue_vars(notSquare(N), Vars), Vars = [_|_]` to see the problem: There are hidden unresolved constraints.

Comment: @false - from top level, `?- member(N,[5,10,17,26,37]), notSquare(N).`, I get `N = 5 ?`; I press semicolon and I get `N = 10 ?`, and `N = 17 ?`, and `N = 26 ?`, and `N = 37 ?`, and (finally) `no`. Take in count that I'm using gprolog (version 1.3.0) and (if I'm not wrong) I can't use `call_residue_vars/2`

Comment: @max66: So far, the question was about SWI/SICStus which features `call_residue_vars/2`. And yes, you cannot directly observe the problem with GNU-Prolog.

Comment: @false so do we need to add more constraints to the definition so that they propagate and resolve them selves?  What do you suggest?

Comment: @user27815: In this particular case it is sufficient to guarantee that a solution exists, as with:   `call_residue_vars(G, XVars), \+ \+ labeling([], XVars)`.