# Compute pairs from two lists that when multiplied make a perfect square

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, perfect-square

You are given two lists and you have to find out the pairs which make a perfect square.

For example in:

```
a = [2, 6, 10, 13, 17, 18]

b = [3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15]
```

There are two pairs `(2,8)` and `(8,18)`.

Is there any method efficient than the brute-force?
Here is my code which has a time complexity of O(n*m)
(where n is the length of a and m is the length of b).

```
pl = []
a = [ 2, 6, 10, 13, 17,18]
b = [ 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15 ]
i = 0
while(i < len(a)):
    j = 0
    while(j < len(b)):
        p = a[i]*b[j]
        n = p**0.5
        u = int(n)
        if n == u:
            pl.append((a[i],b[j]))

        j = j+1


    i = i+1

print(pl)
```

This question has been asked before using C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073103/find-pairs-in-two-arrays-such-that-when-multiplied-becomes-a-perfect-square), but I don't get what they mean by "All we would need to store for each number is which of its prime factors have an odd count", so I can't implement this in my Python code.

Can someone explain to me how we might implement an efficient solution in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic described in the linked question is as follows. A perfect square's prime factors will always be in pairs. For example, `36 = 2*2*3*3`. We have two `3`s and two `2`s. Therefore, if we take any two numbers that multiply to form a perfect square, if we take the combined counts of each of their prime factors, we will also get even counts.

For example, `8 = 2*2*2`, and `18 = 2*3*3`. Combined, we get four `2`s and two `3`s.

Below is some Python code that implements this algorithm, using `collections.Counter` and sets to remove duplicates. First, we precompute all prime factorizations for each unique element in `a` and `b` to avoid redundancy, and store this in a dictionary. Then, we loop over pairs of elements from `a` and `b`, using `itertools.product`, and combine the prime factor counts. If every count is even, we add the sorted pair to a set.

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

def prime_factors(n):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/22808285/12366110
    """
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return Counter(factors)

a = [2, 6, 10, 13, 17,18]

b = [3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15]

prime_factors = {i: prime_factors(i) for i in set(a) | set(b)}

rv = set()

for a, b in itertools.product(a, b):
    combined_counts = prime_factors[a] + prime_factors[b]
    if all(v%2 == 0 for v in combined_counts.values()):
        rv.add(tuple(sorted([a, b])))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
{(2, 8), (8, 18)}
```

Comment: Doesn't `itertools.product(a, b)` make it order m * n though?