# Algorithm to find all possible solutions for x1² + x2² + ... + xn² = 1

Tags: algorithm, math, equation, non-linear

Is there any algorithm to find all possible solutions for this equation:

> x1² + x2² + ... + xn² = 1

Where xi > 0 and n >= 2

To limit solutions we can fix decimal point of x to 1.
For instance:

if n = 2, find all tuples (x1, x2) that satisfies x1² + x2² = 1
The return of this function would be something like (fixing decimal points to 1):

```
[
    [0.1, 1],
    [0.2, 1],
    [0.3, 0.9],
    [0.4, 0.9],
    [0.5, 0.9],
    [0.6, 0.8],
    [0.7, 0.7],
    [0.8, 0.6],
    [0.9, 0.4],
    [1, 0.1],
    [1, 0.2],
    ...
    [0.4, 0.9]
]
```

For n=2 it's easy, but what I need is to generalize for n >= 2.

Comment: Could you show how [0.4, 0.9] gives 1?

Comment: This is a vastly difficult problem afaik. Is it enough to find solutions only in some domain? could define a grid over the domain and iterate Newton's method from each gridpoint, then glob degenerate solutions at the end

Comment: What about *brute force*, testing each `xi` value in range [0.0, 0.1, 0.2,.... 0.9, 1.0] in combination with other `xj` tuples?

Comment: If your question is about the involved math and perhaps algorithms for approximation, math.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask. Putting that into program code is another step then.

Comment: @MBo, the correct result is [0.4, 0.916515138991168], but we are fixing decimal point to 1, so rounding we get [0.4, 0.9].

Comment: @Ripi2 I think is a solution, but I would like some example on a generic algorithm for that.

Comment: you have a specify a solution domain for the brute force approach

Comment: Have a look at the section spherical coordinates of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Comment: If you limit to steps of `0.1`, then it becomes really easy. Just use a `root finding` algorithm to find the roots of `x0**2 + x1**2 - 1`, where `x0` takes values of 0.1, then 0.2, then 0.3, ...., then 1.0, and take note of the output of `x1`. Then, you'll have all combinations of `(x0, x1)` in that domain

Answer (score 3):

First, the equation that you've provided is the general description for a sphere in `R^n` with radius 1. Hence, the number of all possible points is infinite and uncountable!

If you want all points with 1 decimal precision, you can generalize it easily. Suppose you want an algorithm for `n = 3`. Fix `x_3` to a value between 0 to 1 (`0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9`). Then it means you set a plane that intersects a sphere in `R^3`. Now, you want to find `x1` and `x2` such that you have a circle with a radius of `1-x^3` in `R^2`. As you said, you know how to solve it for 2D.

Now you know how to solve the problem for `n = 3`. Hence, you can solve this recursively and generalize it for n > 3.

Comment: I've made this recursive algorithm with brute force. The problem is that it has very high complexity, and became impraticable for n > 8. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @OmG, your equation resembles the equation of an n-Sphere. Trying to find all possible solutions, is therefore hard as there are an infinite amount of them.  A parametrised version of all solutions can be found using a simple parametric equation:

```
2D: x1=cos(t1)                          t1 in [0,2pi[
    x2=sin(t1)
3D: x1=cos(t1)                          t1 in [0,pi]
    x2=sin(t1) cos(t2)                  t2 in [0,2pi[
    x3=sin(t1) sin(t2)
4D: x1=cos(t1)                          t1 in [0,pi]
    x2=sin(t1) cos(t2)                  t2 in [0,pi]
    x3=sin(t1) sin(t2) cos(t3)          t3 in [0,2pi[
    x4=sin(t1) sin(t2) sin(t3)
...
```

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

If you are just interested in solutions upto a given decimal precision, then you should not work with floating points, but integers. Example, if you are interested  in all solutions *x<sub>1</sub>*,*x<sub>2</sub>*,*x<sub>3</sub>* of the equation *x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> = 1*. Where *x<sub>1,2,3</sub>* = *±a.b* with a = 0 or 1 and b is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9. Then it is easier to work with integers to avoid numeric errors due to floating point approximation (See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)). All you need to do is multiply your numbers with 10 (*y<sub>1</sub> = 10 · x<sub>1</sub>*) and solve the equation *y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> = 100* from an integer point-of-view.

A simple and brute-force algorithm, in this case, would just be:

```
do i=0,10
  do j=0,i
    if (i*i + j*j > 100) jump out of j-loop
    do k=0,j
      if (i*i+j*j+k*k == 100) print i,j,k
    end do
  end do
end do
```

The above will print i,j,k. However, all possible permutations and sign-changes valid solutions as well. So the solution (8,6,0) also implies that (-8,6,0), (-6,0,8), (0,8,6), ... are solutions.

So in the end, we reduced the floating-point problem to an integer problem which is easier to check numerically.

Related to this question are now:

- [How many integer solutions are there on an n-dimensional hypersphere of radius r centred at the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810894/539931)
- [Integer lattice points on a hypershpere](https://mathoverflow.net/a/131533)
- [Is there a simple way to compute the number of ways to write a positive integer as the sum of three squares?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3596)
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

If you want to speed things up, you might also be interested in :

- [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579)

Comment: Hey kvantour. Thanks for your reply. I did that, but ending up with a complexity problem, specially when n > 8. For larger n, this brute force solution seems impraticable.

Comment: @PabloAbdelhay that makes complete sens.  With such a high dimensions I would start to think to traverse the grid points around the n-sphere its surface.