# What is wrong of my solution for the Leetcode question Sqrt(x)?

Tags: java, cp

I am trying Leetcode Question - 69. Sqrt(x)
Given a non-negative integer x, compute and return the square root of x.

Since the return type is an integer, the decimal digits are truncated, and only the integer part of the result is returned.

Note: You are not allowed to use any built-in exponent function or operator, such as pow(x, 0.5) or x ** 0.5.

```
class Solution {
    public int mySqrt(int x) {
        int ans = 0;
        
        int i=1;
        while(i*i<=x){
            ans = i;
            i++;
        }        
        return ans;
    }
}
```

This is the code I came up with. But the testcase input=2147395600 is not passing.

My Output = 289398
Expected Output = 46340

I'm confused as I have put the condition i*i<=x, then how can ans be more than the sqrt value?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? Also, you may want to give [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer) a look through.

Comment: You are getting the integer overflow. 46341×46341 is larger than 2**31, so it becomes negative and since negative number is smaller than 'x' the loop continues.Consider using long instead of int.

Comment: You could use long, or you could just rearrange the expression: `while (i <= x / i)` instead of using `while (i*i <= x)`.

Comment: Why use `ans`? `while(i*i < x){ i++;}` then return `i`. I'm surprised you get a return value after an integer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are comparing `i * i` with the input `x`, if the input `x` is too close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2.147.483.647), like in that test case, `i * i` will be bigger than the maximum value allowed for an `int` to have and `i*i<=x` will be true.

Possible solutions:

1. Implement a [binary search algorithm](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/binary-search#:%7E:text=Binary%20search%20is%20an%20efficient,possible%20locations%20to%20just%20one.) where max would be the `floor(sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))` or 46340.
2. Implement a algorithm where `ans`, `i` and `x` are declared locally as `long` type variables and in the return line you return the value cast to `int` using `return (int)ans;`

By running the following algorithm you can see the limit of a java `int` exploding and what happens afterwards.

```java
int x = 2;
while(true) {
    System.out.println(x);
    x *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not pretending to be fast, just the idea that (n+1)<sup>2</sup>=n<sup>2</sup> + 2n + 1:

```java
    public static int mySqrt(int x) {
        int i = 0;
        while (x >= 0) {
            x -= (i++ << 1) + 1;
        }
        return i - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript Solution

```
var mySqrt = function(x) {
var ans = 1;
if(x === 0){
    ans = 0;
} else {
for (let i = 1; i< x;i++){
    if(i*i === x){
        ans = i;
        break;
    }
    if(i*i >x){
        ans = i - 1;
        break;
    }
}
}
return ans;
```

};